# Scrollability of text when using tmux?

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux, terminal-multiplexer, scrolling

Scrollability of text in some terminals:

```
       | tty | xterm | urxvt | guake | terminator
screen |  Y  |   Y   |   Y   |   Y   |     Y
tmux   |  N  |   N   |   Y   |   N   |     N
```

I notice in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549/tmux-vs-gnu-screen/888#888) that scrolling doesn't work when using tmux. But I can scroll in urxvt. How can I have that behaviour in other terminals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `set -g terminal-overrides "xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@"` to your tmux config and restart tmux. If you are not using a terminal matching 'xterm*' you'll have to change it of course.

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks tmux `set-titles` setting/feature: the terminals window title does not update anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the alternate-screen setting to off.

Comment: You mean adding `setw -g alternate-screen off` in `/etc/tmux`? That doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tmux set -g mode-mouse on`

I use an alias "tn" with this (having it as the default in my .tmux.conf didn't work for me, some issue, tl; dr;)

```
alias tn='tmux set -g mode-mouse on'
```

Comment: ran into this, and man pages mentioned it only loaded config file when server first starts, and suggested reloading the tmux.conf file with the source-file command. That worked for me and I can use config file as opposed to the alias trick here.