# .ksh session hangs after being inactive

Tags: shell, ssh

While remotely connecting to a Linux machine using ssh, my .ksh session hangs after being inactive for sometime. If I try to type or ctrl-z, the prompt does not respond. Is there a way to restore my session?

Comment: It's not immediately clear if your *shell* is hung, or if you've lost your ssh session to your shell. Are you trying to troubleshoot this apparent hang, or for ways to maintain a remote session if/when your (ssh) connection drops?

Comment: I login to an ssh session in shell 1, switch to shell 2 to do some piece of work there, come back to shell 1 after 15-20 mins and can't type anything in shell 1. I wish to maintain the remote connection in shell 1.

Comment: Not sure if shell 1 times out or drops the connection or is hung.

Comment: It sounds to me like you've lost your ssh connection. No characters show up in shell 1, and you haven't been returned to your pre-ssh prompt?

Comment: Is there a way to estore and continue the session in shell 1 ?

Comment: Read *restore* in my previous comment.

Comment: How do I return to my pre-ssh prompt?

Comment: If the remote side hasn't closed the ssh connection, then  use shell 2 to kill shell 1's ssh process. Does your remote shell have a TMOUT variable set?

Comment: No. How can I find out about TMOUT?

Comment: ssh back in and run: echo $TMOUT

Comment: Ran echo $TMOUT. Output is 0.

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is that some network equipment somewhere between the client and the server terminates connections that have been idle for a certain time. Such network equipment (firewalls, NAT appliances, …) often kills idle connections after a while to save memory (it's a defense against denial of service, but it does tend to be an annoyance to users).

To avoid this, you can set the `ServerAliveInterval` option in `~/.ssh/config` to a value that's lower than the timeout after which your connections get killed. For example, if your connections get killed when they've been idle for 10 minutes, set `ServerAliveInterval` to 5 minutes:

```
ServerAliveInterval 300
```

Additionally, in case you do get cut off, use a [terminal multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer) on the server: [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux). For example, with Screen, run `screen -rd` on the server when you log in; if you get disconnected, reconnect to the server and run `screen -rd` to reattach to your existing session. See also  and [tmux vs. GNU Screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549/tmux-vs-gnu-screen)