# How can I run a command which will survive terminal close?

Tags: command-line, terminal, process, background-process

Sometimes I want to start a process and forget about it. If I start it from the command line, like this:

```
redshift
```

I can't close the terminal, or it will kill the process. Can I run a command in such a way that I can close the terminal without killing the process?

Comment: Not a default install on all distros, but screen is your friend: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen

Comment: To anyone facing the same problem: Remember, that even if you type `yourExecutable &` and the outputs keep coming on the screen and `Ctrl+C` does not seem to stop anything, just blindly type `disown;` and press `Enter` even if the screen is scrolling with outputs and you can't see what you're typing. The process will get disowned and you'll be able to close the terminal without the process dying.

Comment: You can use screen multiplexer such [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/). It is available via apt-get on ubuntu machines

Answer (score 472, accepted):

One of the following 2 should work:

```
$ nohup redshift &
```

or

```
$ redshift &
$ disown
```

See the following for a bit more information on how this works:

- [`man nohup`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nohup.1.html)
- [`help disown`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#index-disown)
- [Difference between nohup, disown and &](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and) (be sure to read the comments too)

Comment: The second one (`redshift & disown`) worked for me on Ubuntu 10.10. It seems to work fine putting it all on one line. Is there any reason that I shouldn't do this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any particular problem with that construction.

Comment: @Matthew The first should work fine too, it just doesn't background like the second (you possibly want `nohup redshift &` so it does background). And putting the second on one line is fine, although usually you separate with `;` (`redshift &; disown`)

Comment: @Michael: Both `;` and `&` are command separators and have equal precedence. The only difference is the synchronous versus asynchronous execution (respectively). There is no need to use `&;` in preference to just `&` (it works, but it is a bit redundant).

Comment: good answer, one might add that it would be a good idea to redirect stdout and stderr so that the terminal won't be spammed with debug output

Comment: can we prepend `nohup` to any command that we might type in `bash`? If yes, how to make it prepended by default?

Comment: Also, `redshift &!` will disown redshift immediately.

Comment: @stefan because it is easier to  thing ahead. You do not want to have a list of stuff that needs disconnecting, when you close terminal. What if you forget? So do it ahead of time. Also for readshift, consider putting it in user start-up, so that it always runs.

Comment: can't you provide a summary of the difference and save us time from reading the man page? I don't care about the details I just want it to work.

Comment: it does not work for `tint2` :(

Comment: For me only `nohup python3 -m http.server 8000 &` worked, whereas all other will be killed when closing the ssh connection.

Comment: On macOS and zsh, using `nohup command &` resulted in the job being backgrounded, but when I went to exit the terminal session, it said `zsh: you have running jobs.` When I closed the terminal window, the job was no longer running in the background. However, **`command &!` worked a treat!**

Comment: `somecommand > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown somecommand ; exit` (run a command in a background while redirecting all its outputs to nowhere(null), then disown it and close the terminal)

Answer (score 176):

If your program is *already running* you can pause it with `Ctrl-Z`, pull it into the background with `bg` and then `disown` it, like this:

```
$ sleep 1000
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 1000
$ bg
$ disown
$ exit
```

Comment: after disown how can I again read the stdout of the running process?

Comment: @neckTwi, http://serverfault.com/questions/55880/moving-an-already-running-process-to-screen

Comment: This didn't work for me for some reason (centos)

Comment: How to kill the process after this procedure?

Comment: @necktwi `disown` does not disconnect stdout or stderr. However `nohup` does, as does `>/dev/null` (disconnect standard out), `2>/dev/null` (disconnect standard error). It (`disown`) disconnects job-control.

Comment: I couldn't get "nohup google-chrome &" working on Linux Mint (for whatever reason). This solution worked perfectly however, thanks!

Comment: To anyone else finding this, this really messed things up for me so be careful. Ctrl+z stopped it just fine, but bg made it start running again and now it won't respond to Ctrl+Z or Ctrl+C. Now there seems to be no way to exit the running command safely at all. No idea why, just did exactly what it said, but for whatever reason `bg` bought it back running. I can't do the next step of typing `disown` because there's too much output to type anything.

Comment: @robjbrain In bash `jobs` will tell you which jobs are running and their job number. Then use `fg <job #>` to bring a job to the foreground.

Comment: @JohnMellor You were probably running into a similar situation to ctrl-alt-delor's comment, where the program is indeed running in the background but still has its stdout piped to your shell. Ctrl + C and Ctrl + Z won't do anything from here because no program is actually running in the foreground. You can still type in commands from here, like `ls` or `disown` without a problem, it is just really hard to read what you're typing while output is being mixed in with your characters. I just had a similar situation with ffmpeg, but it works fine.

Comment: @palak Foregrounding it again with `fg` probably won't work, but you can [note the PID of the process (in advance)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/441156/318461) [as described in this post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/move-running-process-screen-bruce-werdschinski). You can also consider [the comment by J.Money](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-run-a-command-which-will-survive-terminal-close/4006#comment705176_4010).

Answer (score 60):

*[Good answer is already posted by @Steven D](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4006/318461), yet I think this might clarify it a bit more.*

The reason that the process is killed on termination of the terminal is that the process you start is a child process of the terminal. Once you close the terminal, this will kill these child processes as well. You can see the process tree with `pstree`, for example when running `kate &` in Konsole:

```
init-+
     ├─konsole─┬─bash─┬─kate───2*[{kate}]
     │         │      └─pstree
     │         └─2*[{konsole}]
```

To make the `kate` process detached from `konsole` when you terminate `konsole`, use `nohup` with the command, like this:

```
nohup kate &
```

After closing `konsole`, `pstree` will look like this:

```
init-+
     |-kate---2*[{kate}]
```

and `kate` will survive. :)

An alternative is using `screen`/`tmux`/`byobu`, which will keep the shell running, independent of the terminal.

Comment: I had problems with the disown methods. This is currently working for me, so upvoting. I also like this because I can tail -f nohup.out to see whats happening, but not worry about my session failing

Comment: so after nohup or disown, how do you get the process back? or get access to old stdout?

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendation screen/tmux/byobu.

Answer (score 39):

You can run the process like this in the terminal

```
setsid process
```

This will run the program in a new session, as explained [in my article here](http://hanoo.org/index.php?article=run-program-in-new-session-linux).

Comment: What do you see as the advantages of setsid over nohup?

Comment: 1) It doesn't print an annoying message about `nohup.out`. 2) It doesn't remain in your shell's job list, so it doesn't clutter the output of `jobs`.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for with script that runs in lxterminal, launchs pcmanfm and exit (with setsid the terminal can close while pcmanfm keep running). Thank you so much!

Comment: It works for `tint2`, thanks

Comment: Similar to desgua said with my Fedora GNOME install.  Running a script to open other applications through my fish shell and a desktop application wrapper.  nohup, open, xdg-open were not helping, even with the ampersand (&) and verifying in System Monitor in dependencies/hierarchy/family/tree mode that my new process was not a parent of the originally spawning-shell under gnome-terminal-server that was consistent with non- and actually- -working approaches.

Answer (score 17):

I prefer:

```
(applicationName &)
```

for example:
`linux@linux-desktop:~$ (chromium-browser &)`

Make sure to use parenthesis when type the command!

Comment: Probably you have prompt command that I've used in my answer without parenthesis, if so closing the terminal will kill the process, otherwise it will NOT happen. I've already edited the solution above to make it clear.

Comment: I am wondering why this got not more upvotes. `nohup` prevents any tty output and I actually just wanted redirect the output to a file and it prevented that so this is the better solution to me.

Comment: extremely interesting. clean and uses no additional command. it even plays nicely with sudo.

Comment: Outstanding! I've never been able to figure out how to open apps/files/resources/etc and advance the shell prompt from a single command, until now. So thank you. Can you elaborate on how the shell interprets `(command &)` vs `command &`. Why does the latter wait for more input? Also, if I want to immediately close the terminal after opening a gui app, is it enough to just pass something like `(nautilus path/to/foo/bar/ &) ; exit;` to the shell? Just want to make sure I am not introducing any new problems.

Comment: @NicholasCousar I'm not sure how other shells interpret `(...)` but in Bash that runs `...` in [a subshell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping). (It might be a POSIX standard.)

Answer (score 15):

Though all of the suggestions work well, I've found my alternative is to use `screen`, a program that sets up a virtual terminal on your screen.

You might consider starting it with `screen -S session_name`. Screen can be installed on virtually all Linux and Unix derivatives. Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and (lower case) <kbd>C</kbd> will start a second session. This would allow you to toggle back and forth between the initial session by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>0</kbd> or the newer session by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>1</kbd>. You can have up to ten sessions in one terminal. I used to start a session at work, go home, ssh into my work machine, and then invoke `screen -d -R session_name`. This will reconnect you to that remote session.

Comment: `screen -d -m command` will start it within already detached screen:

`~# screen -d -m top
~# screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        10803..Server-station    (Detached)
1 Socket in /root/.screen.
~# screen -x
`
.... and you're in.

Answer (score 10):

I have a script (I called `run`) to:

- Run arbitrary commands in the background
- Stop them from being killed with the terminal window
- Suppress their output
- Handles exit status

I use it mainly for `gedit`, `evince`, `inkscape` etc that all have lots of annoying terminal output. If the command finishes before `TIMEOUT`, nohup's exit status is returned instead of zero. Contents of  `run`:

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMEOUT=0.1

#use nohup to run the command, suppressing its output and allowing the terminal to be closed
#also send nohup's output to /dev/null, supressing nohup.out
#run nohup in the background so this script doesn't block
nohup "${@}" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
NOHUP_PID=$!

#kill this script after a short time, exiting with success status - command is still running
#this is needed as there is no timeout argument for `wait` below
MY_PID=$$
trap "exit 0" SIGINT SIGTERM
sleep $TIMEOUT && kill $MY_PID 2>/dev/null & #ignore "No such process" error if this exits normally

#if the command finishes before the above timeout, everything may be just fine or there could have been an error
wait $NOHUP_PID
NOHUP_STATUS=$?
#print an error if there was any. most commonly, there was a typo in the command
[ $NOHUP_STATUS != 0 ] && echo "Error ${@}"
#return the exit status of nohup, whatever it was
exit $NOHUP_STATUS
```

**Examples:**

```
>>> run true && echo success || echo fail
success
>>> run false && echo success || echo fail
Error false
fail
>>> run sleep 1000 && echo success || echo fail
success
>>> run notfound && echo success || echo fail
Error notfound
fail
```

Answer (score 9):

The shell-only way to do all this is to close stdin and background the command:

```
command <&- &
```

Then it won't quit when you quit the shell. Redirecting stdout is a nice optional thing to do.

Disadvantage is that you can't do this after the fact.

Comment: I tried in ubuntu. Killing terminal also closed the launched process. Any idea on why this might be the case?

Answer (score 5):

You can set a process (PID) to not receive a HUP signal upon logging out and closing the terminal session.  Use the following command:

```
nohup -p PID
```

Answer (score 4):

Arguably similar to the [answer offered by apolinsky](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185605/100397), I use a variant on `screen`. The vanilla command is like this

```
screen bash -c 'long_running_command_here; echo; read -p "ALL DONE:"'
```

The session can be disconnected with <kbd>Ctrl A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl D</kbd> and reconnected in the simple case with `screen -r`. I have this wrapped in a script called `session` that lives in my `PATH` ready for convenient access:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
if screen -ls | awk '$1 ~ /^[1-9][0-9]*\.'"$1"'/' >/dev/null
then
    echo "WARNING: session is already running (reattach with 'screen -r $1')" >&2
else
    exec screen -S "$1" bash -c "$@; echo; echo '--------------------'; read -p 'ALL DONE (Enter to exit):'"
    echo "ERROR: 'screen' is not installed on this system" >&2
fi
exit 1
```

This only works when you know in advance you want to disconnect a program. It does not provide for an *already running* program to be disconnected.

Answer (score 3):

Similarly to other answers posted before, one can transfer a running process to use `screen` retrospectively thanks to [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) and then close the terminal. The steps are described in this [post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/move-running-process-screen-bruce-werdschinski).
The steps to take are:

1. Suspend the process
2. Resume the process in the background with `bg`
3. `disown` the process
4. Launch a `screen` session
5. Find the PID of the process
6. Use `reptyr` to take over the process