# How can I close a terminal without killing its children (without running `screen` first)?

Tags: bash, terminal, process, kill, job-control

sometimes I run an app in the gnome-terminal, but then I suddenly have to restart gnome or something. I guess the answer to the question is also useful then I want to disconnect from SSH where something is happenning.

Gnome's terminal tree looks like this:

```
gnome-terminal
    bash
        some-boring-process
```

Can I 'detach' `bash` from `gnome-terminal` (or detach `some-boring-process` from bash and redirect its output somewhere)? If I just kill `gnome-terminal`, `bash` will be killed to will all its subprocesses

Comment: Closely related: [How can I run a command which will survive terminal close?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4004/176171) and [Difference between nohup, disown and &](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/176171)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If `some-boring-process` is running in your current bash session:

1. halt it with `ctrl-z` to give you the bash prompt
2. put it in the background with `bg`
3. note the job number, or use the `jobs` command
4. detach the process from this bash session with `disown -h %1` (substitute the actual job number there).

That doesn't do anything to redirect the output -- you have to think of that when you launch your boring process. [Edit] There seems to be a way to redirect it https://gist.github.com/782263

But seriously, look into screen. I have shells on a remote server that have been running for months.

---

Looks like this:

```bsh
$ sleep 999999
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 999999
$ bg
[1]+ sleep 999999 &
$ disown -h %1
```

Comment: Thank you. I selected your answer because it was the only one that answers the question (it was about *already* running process). I'm already using `screen` sometimes, though it has its issues and I don't want to use it for *every* bash session in my life

Comment: You don't use it for every bash session, but for every remote machine where you spend a lot of time.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding information about redirecting the output, please review it!

Comment: [root@server ~]# bg
-bash: bg: current: no such job

Comment: Why I got `bash: bg: current: no such job` ?

Comment: that's awesome maybe you could provide an actual example?  my current best guess would be something like `echo foo bg disown ctrl z` but that seems wrong

Comment: @AlexanderMills, I added a shell session so you can see what it looks like. Hope that helps. You can see "sleep" running in the foreground, blocking my interactive shell. I hit Ctrl-Z, put it in the background and then disowned it.

Comment: thanks, in this case I am looking to issue 1 command from the shell, and the rest be done automatically without more interaction from me

Comment: That's not what this question is asking.

Answer (score 9):

This is exactly what [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) and [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) were created for.  You run the shell inside the screen/tmux session, and you can disconnect/reconnect at will.  You can also have multiple shell sessions running inside one gnome-terminal.

Comment: Thanks, but, as I commented to the accepted answer: 1. the question was about already running process. 2. `screen` has its issues and I don't feel like using it for every bash session in my life

Answer (score 5):

[`screen`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/), [`tmux`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1), or [`dtach`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dtach) (possibly with [`dvtm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/dvtm.1.html)) are all great for this, but if it's something where you didn't think to use one of those, you may be able to leverage [`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

Comment: Thanks, but, as I commented to the accepted answer: 1. the question was about already running process. 2. `screen` has its issues and I don't feel like using it for every bash session in my life

Comment: @valya Glad you found a solution. Just to be clear, though, `nohup` does work on a running process by using the `-p` option (if available).

Comment: @Hank Gay: I can't see a `-p` option to `nohup` in the man pages; what system are you on?

Comment: @Mikel Before I learned to stop worrying and love the `tmux`, I used the `-p` option on a Solaris box. I also have vague memories of doing it on a mongrel CentOS box (possibly `zsh` has a builtin that supports it?), but I can't find any docs on that.

Comment: @Hank Gay: Neither `bash` nor `zsh` on my Ubuntu Linux system provide `nohup`.

Comment: @Mikel that combined with my failure to find any docs makes me think I just imagined that. The Solaris thing was real, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep interacting with the child process rather than just backgrounding it and having it keep going, there's actually a program called [retty](http://pasky.or.cz/~pasky/dev/retty/) which is a proof-of-concept for "stealing" a process from its current tty and reattaching it to the current one.

It, however, does some horrible things, including sticking some assembly code on to the stack of the re-attached application. And that code hasn't been updated for x86_64.

There's another program which takes a maybe-better approach, freezing the process in user-space to a file, from which it can later be restored (possibly on another tty.) This is [cryopid](http://cryopid.berlios.de/), and that project too seems to have stopped in the proof-of-concept phase, and doesn't work with modern Linux as the code stands. Ah well.

Just thought this should be here for completeness. If you don't mind resorting to horrible voodoo, this is within the realm of possibility -- at least, theoretical possibility.

Comment: that reminds me of https://gist.github.com/782263 ... oh, that gist seems to answer my question, too

Answer (score 1):

If I fire something up which I want to finish no matter what (short of system reboot), I use `nohup` and run it in the background.  Unlike screen and the like you can't reattach to the processs. However, baring redirection elsewhere any output can be found in `nohup.out`.

I do use `screen` when I want to be able to switch terminals for a process. Such as starting a process from home/work and switching to the other.  Like any other terminal session output will eventual scroll off the top of the buffer.

EDIT: If you have already launched the process, you can `disown` the process to prevent the `HUP` signal from being sent when the process closes.

Comment: Thanks, but, as I commented to the accepted answer: 1. the question was about already running process. 2. `screen` has its issues and I don't feel like using it for every bash session in my life

Comment: @valya I have seen references to disconnecting a running process from the program group.  I don't know of any tools to do so though.  The tool would likely need to redirect the std IO channels as well.  I think I may have got it to work once, but decided nohup was simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a process (PID) not receive a HUP signal when the terminal session is ended.  Use the following command:

```
nohup -p PID
```

Comment: `nohup: invalid option -- 'p'`. What version of `nohup` are you running on what kind of system?

Comment: I mostly use Solaris and AIX.  For Linux, you should check into the disown command.

Comment: Yeah, there's no `-p` option on Linux , so this answer is Solaris and AIX specific. Good to know though

Answer (score 0):

This script detaches child process from parent and assigns it to **init** process:

```
toDetach=$1

./$toDetach & # Runs the process - script on background

disown -h %$(jobs -l | grep $(ps -A | grep $toDetach | cut --delimiter=' ' -f1) | cut --delimiter=' ' -f1 | tr -d '[]+') # and then disowns it from parents process
```