# How can I switch between ttys without using screen?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, terminal-multiplexer

So let's say you boot up your Linux install all the way to the desktop. You start up a gnome-terminal/konsole/whatever so you have a tty to enter commands to.

Now let's say I SSH into that same machine. It will bind me to another tty to enter commands to.

Now let's say I want to "switch" my tty from my original SSH one to the gnome-terminal one started earlier.

Basically I'm asking if there is any way to do the same thing `screen -x` does but without screen?

I know you can easily send output to the other tty simply by echoing something into the /dev file, but I don't know a way to 'view' what's in the tty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related question: [What happens to the output of a process that has been disowned and lost its terminal?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17648/1925)

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8469/closing-a-terminal-without-killing-its-children ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe these schema can clarify the situation.
This is the usual setting:

> ```
>                                Terminal  (/dev/ttyX or /dev/pts/x)
>                                 device
>                                    |
>                     (screen)<--[<output]----x-------(stdout) Process1
>         Terminal  (keyboard)---[input >]---o-\----->(stdin)
>                                             \ \
> (hardware console or                         \ `----(stdout) Process2
>  virtual console or terminal                  `---->(stdin)
>  emulators like xterm, …)
> ```

And there is **no** way to plug some new `Process3` like this:

> ```
>                              Terminal
>                               device
>                                  |
>              (screen)<---o---[<output]--x------(stdout) Process1
>   Terminal (keyboard)---/-x--[input >]-o-\---->(stdin)
>                        | /              \ \
>                        | |               \ `---(stdout) Process2
>                        | |                `--->(stdin)
>                        | |
>                        \ `---------------------(stdout) Process3
>                         `--------------------->(stdin)
> ```

What screen (and others) does is allocating some pseudo terminal device (like xterm does) and redirect it to one or more "real" terminals (physical, virtual, or emulated):

> ```
>              Terminal                   pseudo
>              devices              ,--> Terminal (/dev/pts/x)
>                 |         _______/      device
> Terminal <--[<output]--- |       |        |
>  1       ---[input >]--> |screen | <--[<output]---x-----(stdout) Process1
>                          |Process| ---[input >]--o-\--->(stdin)
> Terminal <--[<output]--- |       |                \ \
>  2       ---[input >]--> |_______|                 \ `--(stdout) Process2
>                                                     `-->(stdin)
> ```

Using `screen -x` you can attach one more terminal, xterm, whatever (say `Terminal 3`) to the screen session.

So no, you can't communicate directly through stdin/stdout with processes attached to a different terminal. You can only do so through the process that is controlling this terminal if it happens to be a pseudo terminal, and if this process was concieved to do so (like screen is).

Comment: That's a great explanation! I think it's not really an answer here, but would suit [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17648/what-happens-to-the-output-of-a-process-that-has-been-disowned-and-lost-its-termi) well. One observation: “there is no way” is only true if you forbid `ptrace`; thanks to `ptrace`, programs like `neercs`, `retty` and so on can do it sometimes.

Comment: @Gilles: well they do something else: they change the value of the file descriptors (`stdin`,`stdout` on the right of the schema) directly by hijacking the process. Pure evil!

Comment: Hmm, you're right, they change a different arrow. Evil, but convenient!

Answer (score 9):

Reconnecting the processes on the other terminal to your current terminal is not possible without dirty tricks. It is possible by forcing the process to perform certain system calls (with [`ptrace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace)); this causes some programs to crash. There are several tools that do this, such as `neercs`, `retty`, `cryopid`, `reptyr`, …; see [How can I disown it a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-it-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell) and linked questions.

Obtaining the output already displayed on the other terminal is a different problem. There is no fully general solution: in principle, once the output has been rendered, the terminal might store it only as an image. In practice, all X terminal emulators keep their output buffer in text form so that you can copy-paste it. The way to grab that output depends on the terminal emulator; the basic idea is to simulate selecting the whole scrollback buffer. For a Linux console such as `/dev/tty1`, the scrollback buffer is easily available as `/dev/vcs1` (and `/dev/vcsa1` with text attributes).

The simple answer is that if you want to reconnect to a terminal from a different place, use `screen` or `tmux`.