# Is it possible to detach a process started from one ssh session using another ssh session?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disown it a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-it-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)

I started a process from one ssh session to a target machine `T`. The system from which I ssh'ed, `A`,  hung. I checked using ssh from another machine, `B` that the process is still running on `T`. Now I want to be able to restart `A` without affecting the run of the process on `T`. I had forgotten to use screen or byobu etc. Since `A` is currently hung, I cant even do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>z</kbd>  and disown or something. What can be done ? I dont want the process to terminate but I want to be able to restart `A` which has hung.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to send a SIGCONT signal to the process, but as rozcietrzewiacz mentions, you may need to do some trickery with file descriptors if the process requires terminal access.

kill -CONT *pid*

If this still comes up as `T`, then it likely needs user input.

Answer (score 1):

You might modify the file descriptors attached to that process but, in general, doing so requires some a bit dirty tricks to be used. The whole concept is quite nicely covered in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17838/how-can-i-switch-between-ttys-without-using-screen/17902#17902). Whether running a program like `retty` will succeed in your case, depends on how rigorously the *process* monitors the status of its own file descriptors.