# Redirect hard return to other terminal

Tags: bash, shell-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Construct a command by putting a string into a tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48103/construct-a-command-by-putting-a-string-into-a-tty)

Suppose I've run a command in a terminal ( `/dev/pts/1` )
and it starts to ask me for input ( "press y to confirm" )
and I want to write 'y --hard return --' 50 times to that terminal from another. How could I do this?

Comment: If the process is already started you can't without dirty tricks. See the answers here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17838/how-can-i-switch-between-ttys-without-using-screen

Comment: Using the TIOCSTI ioctl: `perl -le 'require "sys/ioctl.ph"; ioctl(STDIN, &TIOCSTI, $_) for split "", "y\r" x 50' < /dev/pts/1`