# Completely disown background process

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, tty, disown

I have a bg process disowned like so:

```
 (idea "$code_home/jenkins-jobs" ) & disown
```

The problem is it will start writing its stdout/stderr to the terminal from which I launched it. I would have guessed that disowning a process would tell it to write its stdio to /dev/null unless instructed to write it somewhere.

So my question is - how do I completely disown a process so it stops interacting with my terminal altogether? Is it enough to do something like this?

```
  (idea "$code_home/jenkins-jobs" &> /dev/null ) &> /dev/null & disown
```

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8469/4667

Comment: I think it's not necessary to use a subshell. I think: `some_program >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null & disown` is sufficient -- you're forgetting the `I` in "stdio"

Comment: thanks glenn, see my comment to your answer. a working example there would help, and please add a working example to this question and I will upvote, ty.

Comment: Feel free to test it out and add your own answer.

Comment: thanks, I added a comment to the other answer, I said: "thanks, in this case I am looking to issue 1 command from the shell, and the rest be done automatically without more interaction from me"

Comment: Yes I know, you don't have to repeat it here. I said the other question was "related" not "a duplicate".

Comment: `disown` doesn't do anything else than make _bash_ forget about a job. The disowned process(es) have no clue that they have been disowned. `disown` will NOT magically cause them to redirect their i/o, stop interacting with the user, survive HUP signals, ignore TTIN signals or other marvelous actions.