# How to run regular programs as daemons/services

Tags: command-line, services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I close a terminal without killing the command running in it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-close-a-terminal-without-killing-the-command-running-in-it)

I'm using Debian for my Server.

I just installed MediaCore, which works well.

Now I want to have it always started and want to ask, how it'd be possible to start it as a service or in the background.

I know how to start but then the shell is useless as long as the program runs.

So how can I run it silently, as I run services/daemons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple options.

First, you can launch it in `screen` and then Ctrl-A out of the screen after it launches.  You can later reattach to the screen with a `screen -RR {screen number}`; you can figure out the screen number with a `screen -ls`.  (If you only have one active screen a simple `screen -RR` will reattach).

Second, you can launch it from the shell and background it by appending an `&` after the command.  However, you also want to redirect stdout and stderr to appropriate files so the shell isn't interspersing output of the command with your shell.  I think something like

`$ command > command.stdout 2> command.stderr &`

is what you are looking for.

I've never used MediaCore so I don't know what it outputs.  If you just want to capture all output to a file whether from stdout or stderr, this will work

`$ command &> command.output &`

However, in the long run, since you are using Debian, the right thing to do is add an init script for it (as @user606723 mentioned).  There is a `skeleton` script in `/etc/init.d` that would be a good starting point.

Comment: Note that if you read the screen man file, you can execute screen inside of a script with a certain executable and still add that into init.d. I've done this before because I wanted it automatically executing but I also wanted to be able to interact with it later if needed. (Non-OSS program, not very flexible).

Answer (score 0):

You may run your program with 'screen' or use 'hohup' for detaching from terminal.

```
nohup my_app 2>/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

OR

```
screen -d -m my_app
```

Comment: You should also consider adding it to init.d (or similar). And, you don't necessarily need to &> /dev/null, it might be useful to put that towards some sort of log file. You might also consider making a special user just for the program.