# Launch independent process

Tags: process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I close a terminal without killing the command running in it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-close-a-terminal-without-killing-the-command-running-in-it)

If I open a terminal emulator, type `firefox &` and then close the terminal, the process it launched -Firefox- gets killed as it was its child.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: in any case, for most cases a "Run program..."-style launcher will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `disown` command.  In `zsh` you can also use `&|` to background and disown in a single operation.

```
$ firefox &
[1] 74773
$ disown %1 # or "disown %firefox"
$ firefox &| # zsh only; bash will report "syntax error near unexpected token `|'"
```

Comment: cool! apparently one can't do it in one line right? will consider switching to zsh.

Comment: I couldn't find one, sadly.  Possibly someone more expert in `bash` knows a trick, other than a shell function that manipulates job control to do it.

Comment: @vemv try `nohup`. Example - `nohup firefox`