# How to execute shell commands in a loop from within a bash script?

Tags: shell, scripting

I want to write a script which will run on my android phone & perform the following things:

```
echo "1" > /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run
```

wait for 2 minutes: then

```
echo "0" > /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run
```

then wait for 2-3hrs & loop over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sleep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_%28Unix%29) with [`while` loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop) as follows:

```
while true;
do
echo "1" > /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run;
sleep 120;
echo "0" > /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run;
sleep 7200;
done;
```

Here, `while` Loop starts with condition `while true;` that means no condition for stopping loop (it runs forever until script is killed) then commands will be run (with *`sleep`ing* as you wish) at `done;` loop will be redirected to condition that is `while true;` thus, It will again start executing commands.

Note: with GNU sleep you can also use `sleep 2m`, `sleep 2h` etc.

Comment: it works thanks,but any way to run this script on ram or something that even if i close terminal emulator it keeps running 

comments

Comment: @Roshansingh for closing terminal without killing command, visit [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4006/66803)