# Why do I get permission denied error when I log out of the SSH session?

Tags: ssh, permissions, tmux, kerberos, afs

I have to run some tests on a server at the University. I have ssh access to the server from the desktop in my office. I want to launch a python script on the server that will run several tests during the weekend.

The desktop in the office will go on standby during the weekend and as such it is essential that the process continues to run on the server even when the SSH session gets terminated.

I know about `nohup` and `screen` and `tmux`, as described in questions like:

- [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/q/8653)
- [How can I close a terminal without killing the command running in it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-close-a-terminal-without-killing-the-command-running-in-it)

What am I doing right now is:

- `ssh username@server`
- `tmux`
- `python3 run_my_tests.py`  -> this script does a bunch of `subprocess.check_output` of an other script which itself launches some Java processes.
- Tests run fine.
- I use Ctrl+B, D and I detach the session.
- When doing `tmux attach` I reobtain the tmux session **which is still running fine, no errors whatsoever**. I kept checking this for minutes and the tests run fine.
- I close the ssh session

After this if I log in to the server via SSH,  I **do** am able to reattach to the running `tmux` session, *however* what I see is something like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_my_examples.py", line 70, in <module>
  File "run_my_examples.py", line 62, in run_cmd_aggr
  File "run_my_examples.py", line 41, in run_cmd
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 537, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1456, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I.e. the process that was spawning my running tests, *right after the end of the SSH session*, was completely unable to spawn other subprocesses. I have `chmod`ed the permissions of all files involved and nothing changes.

I believe the servers use Kerberos for login/permissions, the server is Scientific Linux 7.2.

Could it be possible that the permissions of spawning new processes get removed when I log off from the ssh sessions? Is there something I can do about it? I have to launch *several* tests, with no idea how much time or space they will take...

---

- The version of `systemd` is 219
- The file system is AFS, using `fs listacl <name>` I can confirm that I do have permissions over the directories/files that are used by the script.

Comment: Are you using systemd 230 or more recent?  Possibly related to https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825394

Comment: @user4556274 Trying `systemd-run --version` tells me the server is using `systemd 219`.

Comment: @user4556274 In any case I can confirm that the problem is not that the processes are killed, in fact they do keep running, but that they behave differently. As I said I have a script that contains a simple `while True:` loop and that script runs fine, is not killed and I'm able to resume it without problems. I have also tried to add some `subprocess` and `multiprocessing` calls and they work fine. I'm at a loss of what is happening.

Comment: Does the python script reside on an AFS or NFS filesystem?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick According to `df -T` it's an AFS file system. could this be that the various files are on different devices and I need a session to let a program access  the data on other part of the file system?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Checking with `fs listacl <name>` I am listed as having normal access to all relevant directories/files.

Comment: An explanation of what's going on is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571012/how-to-provide-an-already-running-process-with-kerberos-and-afs-ticket . I don't have experience with AFS, but some pointers on how to extend access to the Kerberos tickets and AFS are given in that question's answers.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Seems like launching a new window with `kinit && aklog` is doing the trick. I'm now verifying this by detaching, waiting some time rebooting and see if the processes are still running, or if they get the permission error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [Mark Plotnick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/49439/mark-plotnick) I was able to identify and fix the issue.

The problem is the interaction between the [AFS file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_File_System) used by the server and Kerberos handling the authentication. The same issue was brought up in [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571012/how-to-provide-an-already-running-process-with-kerberos-and-afs-ticket).

Basically what is happening is that when I ssh into the server, Kerberos gives the authentication token to the session. This token is used also to access the AFS file system. When closing the SSH session this token gets destroyed and the processes running start to get permission denied errors when trying to access files on the AFS.

The way to fix this is to start a new window inside `screen`/`tmux` and launch the command:

```
kinit && aklog
```

After that you can detach from `screen`/`tmux` and close the ssh session safely.

The commands above create new Kerberos tokens and associate those with the `screen`/`tmux` session, in this way when the ssh connection is closed the initial tokens get revoked but since the subprocesses now use those you created they don't suffer permission denied errors.

---

To summarize:

- `ssh username@server`
- `tmux`
- Launch the process you need to keep running
- Create a new window with <kbd>Ctrl+B, C</kbd>
- `kinit && aklog`
- Detach from the session with <kbd>Ctrl+B, D</kbd>
- Close ssh session

Comment: Could you please check? Ctrl+A,C kills the process in the current screen, how can this be fixed?

Comment: @Sumit it's `CTRL+B, C` using `tmux`.

Answer (score 0):

Such errors probably related to the filesystem permissions.
Can you take a look on the server-side syslog events?

Maybe you need to stay logged in your environment
Take a look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/linux-access-privileges-2-access-again.html) to know more about Linux file permissions and issues, it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `screen ssh $USER@$HOSTNAME` on server.

The `kinit && aklog` solution didn't work for me, but I found this "sshception" solution. Within screen, I ssh into the same machine and run my programs in that ssh session. Even if screen loses permission, the ssh session inside stays open and authenticated.