# Trying to write a shell script that keeps testing a server remotely, but it keeps falling in else statement when I logout

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep, ping, bourne-shell

Trying here to write a shell script that keeps testing my server and email me when it becomes down.

The problem is that when I logout from ssh connection, despite running it with `&` at the end of command, like `./stest01.sh &`, it automatically falls into else and keeps mailing me uninterruptedly, until I log again and kill it.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    date > sdown.txt ;
    cp /dev/null pingop.txt ;
    ping -i 1 -c 1 -W 1 myserver.net > pingop.txt &
    sleep 1 ;
    if
        grep "64 bytes" pingop.txt ;
    then
        :
    else
        mutt -s "Server Down!" myemail@address.com < sdown.txt ;
        sleep 10 ;
    fi
done
```

Comment: I am not a bash expert, but what does the colon `:` do?  It would make sense to me it it were a semicolon `;`...

Comment: @Ned64 The `:` does nothing. This is what it is designed to do. Here, instead of inverting the test, they use it to do a no-op before `else`.

Comment: @Kusalananda OK, thanks. Thought it might be a typo that could explain the problem.

Comment: I'm also confused why one would try to leave a shell script running after logout. Wouldn't cron or systemd timers be a better choice for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a command which will survive terminal close?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-run-a-command-which-will-survive-terminal-close)

Comment: It's been working swiftly after added `-q` in `grep` command!

Comment: The main diferences from this question is that it involves `if` command usage, `grep` command options, such as `-q`, which solved my problem, the explanation of colon and semicolon usage, some difference between the operation of `grep` command in BSD and GNU systems!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When GNU `grep` tries to write its result, it will fail with a non-zero exit status, because it has nowhere to write the output, because the SSH connection is gone.

This means that the `if` statement is always taking the `else` branch.

To illustrate this (this is not *exactly* what's happening in your case, but it shows what happens if GNU `grep` is unable to write its output):

```
$ echo 'hello' | grep hello >&- 2>&-
$ echo $?
2
```

Here we `grep` for the string that `echo` produces, but we close both output streams for `grep` so that it can't write anywhere. As you can see, the exit status of GNU `grep` is 2 rather than 0.

This is particular to GNU `grep`, `grep` on BSD systems won't behave the same:

```
$ echo 'hello' | grep hello >&- 2>&-    # using BSD grep here
$ echo $?
0
```

To remedy this, make sure that the script does not generate output.  You can do this with `exec >/dev/null 2>&1`.  Also, we should be using `grep` with its `-q` option since we're not at all interested in *seeing* the output from it (this would generally also speed up the `grep` as it does not need to parse the whole file, but in this case it make very little difference in speed since the file is so small).

In short:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# redirect all output not redirected elsewhere to /dev/null by default:
exec >/dev/null 2>&1

while true; do
    date >sdown.txt

    ping -c 1 -W 1 myserver.net >pingop.txt

    if ! grep -q "64 bytes" pingop.txt; then
        mutt -s "Server Down!" myemail@address.com <sdown.txt
        break
    fi

    sleep 10
done
```

You may also use a test on `ping` directly, removing the need for one of the intermediate files (and also getting rid of the other intermediate file that really only ever contains a datestamp):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

exec >/dev/null 2>&1

while true; do
    if ! ping -q -c 1 -W 1 myserver.net; then
        date | mutt -s "Server Down!" myemail@address.com
        break
    fi

    sleep 10
done
```

In both variations of the script above, I choose to exit the loop upon failure to reach the host, just to minimise the number of emails sent. You could instead replace the `break` with e.g. `sleep 10m` or something if you expect the server to eventually come up again.

I've also slightly tweaked the options used with `ping` as `-i 1` does not make much sense with `-c 1`.

Shorter (unless you want it to continue sending emails when the host is unreachable):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

exec >/dev/null 2>&1

while ping -q -c 1 -W 1 myserver.net; do
    sleep 10
done

date | mutt -s "Server Down!" myemail@address.com
```

As a cron job running every minute (would continue sending emails every minute if the server continues to be down):

```
* * * * * ping -q -c 1 -W 1 >/dev/null 2>&1 || ( date | mail -s "Server down" myemail@address.com )
```

Comment: Using `>&-` will close the fd (as in, file descriptor 1 is closed), while closing the SSH connection will have a different effect (a file descriptor will be still around, but not connected to anything on the other side.) I think the point still stands, which is that GNU grep exits non-zero if it tries to write output and that fails. Yeah, best solution is just checking exit status of ping directly.

Comment: It might be safer to just redirect everything to/from /dev/null for the entire script by adding `exec </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1` near the beginning. That way if e.g. `ping` decides to write something to stderr it won't cause a problem.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I don't really see a reason to pull stdin from `/dev/null` here, but I sorted out the output. Thanks for the suggestion.