# process is still interrupted with closing ssh connection after disown

Tags: ssh, disown

After running a process, then using:

```
ctrl+z
bg
disown [-h]
```

Closing the connection still results in interrupting the running process.

Comment: nohup and screen are far better options. What process are you running and why are you so determined to use disown?

Comment: yeah i usually use nohup but the question is about a process that is already running

Comment: the process is a python script to train a model that has been running for a while and i would prefer to not interrupt it at this point

Comment: You can't disown a pid or process, you disown a job. Run jobs command and see if your script is there. Then run disown %jobnumber

Comment: yeah this is what i did. it still didn't work. i also checked jobs after disown

Comment: jobs are empty but still closing the connection kills the process

Comment: Possibly useful, depending on what your ultimate goal is: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4034/315749

Comment: why do you believe that `disown` would prevent that from happening?

Comment: Your background job would still die if a) it's stopped and it doesn't catch the `SIGHUP` signal b) it tries to write to the terminal which no longer exists, gets an error, and exits with an error message which goes nowhere c) systemd kills it (this was debated at long) or d) something else. `nohup` will only help with a). I suggest you attach to it from another terminal/ssh connection with `strace -fp PID`, and see what's actually happening.

Comment: @Alex a job is a *process group*. When you run `foo &`, or `foo` followed by Ctrl-Z and `bg`, you have `foo` as a job with a single process, and that's the job `disown` without arguments will remove from the bash's jobs table, **without** detaching it from the terminal or downgrading it from a job to a simple process or other nonsensical magical actions.

Comment: @UncleBilly thanks yeah it was actually writing to the terminal and i suspected it's the reason it got terminated after disconnecting. There were some comments like the ones under this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4010/374091 that got me thinking it should actually work