# Kill all descendant processes

Tags: process, kill

I'm writing an application. It has the ability to spawn various external processes. When the application closes, I want any processes it has spawned to be killed.

Sounds easy enough, right? Look up my PID, and recursively walk the process tree, killing everything in sight, bottom-up style.

Except that this doesn't *work*. In one specific case, I spawn `foo`, but `foo` just spawns `bar` and then immediately exits, leaving `bar` running. There is now *no record* of the fact that `bar` was once part of the application's process tree. And hence, the application has no way of knowing that it should kill `bar`.

I'm pretty sure I can't be the first person on Earth to try to do this. So what's the standard solution? I guess really I'm looking for some way to "tag" a process in such a way that any process it spawns will unconditionally inherit the same tag.

(So far, the best I can come up with is running the application as a different user. That way, you can just indescriminently kill all processes beloning to that user. But this has all sorts of access permission problems...)

Comment: Have you thought about having the nth child process self reap rather than killing it?

Comment: Closely related: [Process descendants](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14815/process-descendants/14853#14853). [Process groups](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124130) are the way to go if they work for you.

Comment: @Gilles I disagree that PGID is the best way to do this. For me simply doing `sh -c 'sleep 10m' & ps -jH` shows that the `sh` command has a different `PGID` from the calling shell.

Comment: protip: if you use systemd, you can tell it to keep track of this for you using cgroups.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

## Update

This is one of those ones where I clearly should have read the question more carefully (though seemingly this is the case with most answers on to this question). I have left the original answer intact because it gives some good information, even though it clearly misses the point of the question.

### Using SID

I think the most general, robust approach here (at least for Linux) is to use SID (Session ID) rather than PPID or PGID. This is much less likely to be changed by child processes and, in the case of shell script, the `setsid` command can be used to start a new session. Outside of the shell the `setuid` system call can be used.

For a shell that is a session leader, you can kill all the other processes in the session by doing (the shell won't kill itself):

```
kill $(ps -s $$ -o pid=)
```

Note: The trailing equals sign in argument `pid=` removes the `PID` column header.

Otherwise, using system calls, call `getsid` for each process seems like the only way.

### Using a PID namespace

This is the most robust approach, however the downsides are that it is Linux only and that it needs root privileges. Also the shell tools (if used) are very new and not widely available.

For a more detailed discussion of PID namespaces, please see this question - [Reliable way to jail child processes using `nsenter:`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124162/reliable-way-to-jail-child-processes-using-nsenter). The basic approach here is that you can create a new PID namespace by using the `CLONE_NEWPID` flag with the `clone` system call (or via the `unshare` command).

When a process in a PID namespace is orphaned (ie when it parent process finishes), it is re-parented to the top level PID namespace process rather than the `init`. This means that you can always identify all the descendants of the top level process by walking the process tree. In the case of a shell script the PPID approach below would then reliably kill all descendants.

Further reading on PID namespaces:

- [Namespaces in operation, part 3: PID namespaces](https://lwn.net/Articles/531419/)
- [Namespaces in operation, part 4: more on PID namespaces](https://lwn.net/Articles/532748/)

## Original Answer

### Killing child processes

The easy way to do this in a shell script, provided `pkill` is available is:

```
pkill -P $$
```

This kills all children of the current given process (`$$` expands to the PID of the current shell).

### Killing all descendent processes

Another situation is that you may want to kill all the descendants of the current shell process as well as just the direct children. In this case you can use the recursive shell function below to list all the descendant PIDs, before passing them as arguments to kill:

```
list_descendants ()
{
  local children=$(ps -o pid= --ppid "$1")

  for pid in $children
  do
    list_descendants "$pid"
  done

  echo "$children"
}

kill $(list_descendants $$)
```

### Double forks

One thing to beware of, which might prevent the above from working as expected is the double `fork()` technique. This is commonly used when daemonising a process. As the name suggests the process that is to be started runs in the second fork of the original process. Once the process is started, the first fork then exits meaning that the process becomes orphaned.

In this case it will become a child of the `init` process instead of the original process that it was started from. There is no robust way to identify which process was the original parent, so if this is the case, you can't expect to be able to kill it without having some other means of identification (a PID file for example). However, if this technique has been used, you shouldn't try to kill the process without good reason.

Further Reading:

- [Why fork() twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932592/why-fork-twice)
- [What is the reason for performing a double fork when creating a daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/what-is-the-reason-for-performing-a-double-fork-when-creating-a-daemon)

Comment: The descendant process needn't double fork - it can fork once, but if it does so it will be orphaned if its parent process later forks. This occurs all of the time, and is not necessarily related to intentional daemonization at all.

Comment: But we've all already answered how to kill all child processes in various ways - the question is not how to ensure one process becomes and remains the child of another. Can you get in `testing`? Besides, I already did it: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124162/reliable-way-to-jail-child-processes-using-nsenter

Comment: @mikserv, ok, I'll have a go. If Gilles doesn't get there first :)

Comment: This misses all cases where a child dies before the grandchild.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you kill the process running as pid 1 via `unshare -p`? I had hoped that this would reliably kill all processes below it, so that you can "clean up" by killing a single process/cgroup root. But it seems that this results in all child processes to be reparented to the outer `init`.

Comment: Turns out it works with `unshare -pf` but not with `unshare -p`. I've asked a [separate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393210/why-does-unshare-based-killing-only-work-reliably-with-fork) to find out why.

Comment: @Graeme This is now possible with util-linux `2.32`. Using `unshare -fp --kill-child -- yourprogram`, if you kill `unshare`, all child processes will be killed. [I implemented this upstream](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393279/100270). Would you mind updating your answer?

Comment: `pkill -P $$` worked on my workstation but not on travis CI -- for whatever reason it kills the shell's process as well.  I also did not have luck with `kill $(ps...)`.  Yet another way to do this is: `jobs -p | xargs -n 1 pkill -P`.  (This enumerates the pids of the child jobs and passes each to `pkill -P`.)

Comment: Be careful copying `$(ps -p $$ -o ssid=)` as `ps` may sometimes add leading whitespace to the result. To remove all whitespace, use `$(ps -p $$ --no-headers -o ssid:1)`. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153157/format-ps-command-output-without-whitespace). Doesn't affect this answer but important if you want to store SID into a variable.

Comment: The answer states that "Using a [Linux] PID namspace ... needs root privileges."  This is incorrect.  On appropriately compiled recent Linux kernels, a non-root user can create a user namespace, and a user namespace can include a PID namespace.  See `man 7 user_namespaces`.  And possibly also `man 1 unshare`.

Comment: How do you get the SID of a process? Man pages talk about getsid, but it's not available in Arch Linux 5.11.2-arch1-1 or Ubuntu 20.10. Tried searching for getsid online, but only found a few man pages including from Ubuntu. My polybar isn't cleanly closing through autorandr and all the child processes have different PPID and PGRP, but has the same SID.

Comment: @gavsiu it should show up with `ps -j` or `ps -o sess` or `ps -o sid`.

Comment: Thanks. Those commands do work as intended, but killing using SID is not the solution to my problem because apparently it's not just polybar using the same SID. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: `ps --ppid` [does not appear to be specified](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/ps.html) by POSIX, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @AdrianGünter, well spotted. Took that part out of the answer

Comment: @Graeme that's unfortunate, as I was specifically on the hunt for a POSIX-compatible method. :P Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be easily doable, although I remember taking the pains once a few years back and arriving at a workable solution. Alas...

Comment: @AdrianGünter, you can't just do something along the lines of `ps -o ppid -o pid | grep "^$$" | cut -f 2` ?

Comment: @Graeme Perhaps, I'll have to give it a try!

Answer (score 30):

You can use:

```
kill -TERM -- -XXX
```

where `XXX` is group number of process group you want to kill. You can check it using:

```
 $ ps x -o  "%p %r %c"
 PID   PGID COMMAND
 2416  1272 gnome-keyring-d
 2427  2427 gnome-session
 2459  2427 lightdm-session <defunct>
 2467  2467 ssh-agent
 2470  2427 dbus-launch
 2471  2471 dbus-daemon
 2484  2427 gnome-settings-
 2489  2471 gvfsd
 2491  2471 gvfs-fuse-daemo
 2499  2427 compiz
 2502  2471 gconfd-2
 2508  2427 syndaemon
 2513  2512 pulseaudio
 2517  2512 gconf-helper
 2519  2471 gvfsd-metadata
```

For more details about process groups ID, you can see `man setpgid`:

```
DESCRIPTION
       All  of  these interfaces are available on Linux, and are used for get‐
       ting and setting the process group ID (PGID) of a  process.   The  pre‐
       ferred,  POSIX.1-specified  ways  of doing this are: getpgrp(void), for
       retrieving the calling process's PGID; and  setpgid(),  for  setting  a
       process's PGID.

       setpgid()  sets  the  PGID of the process specified by pid to pgid.  If
       pid is zero, then the process ID of the calling process  is  used.   If
       pgid is zero, then the PGID of the process specified by pid is made the
       same as its process ID.  If setpgid() is used to move  a  process  from
       one  process  group to another (as is done by some shells when creating
       pipelines), both process groups must be part of the same  session  (see
       setsid(2)  and  credentials(7)).   In  this case, the pgid specifies an
       existing process group to be joined and the session ID  of  that  group
       must match the session ID of the joining process.
```

Comment: How do process groups work? Most of the tasks in your example seem to be in one of two groups...

Comment: It's a result of forking from shell command line or server startup. It's only short example.

Comment: The process group _looks like_ it might be the thing I'm looking for, but I still want to understand exactly when two processes will have the same group ID, and when it will be different.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid You should probably do `man nsenter` and have a look here: http://lwn.net/Articles/531114/

Comment: PGID is not a reliable way to identify children of a particular process since `setpgid()` can be called on any process. PPID is a more robust way since this is more difficult to alter.

Comment: @Graeme - PPID is pretty easy to alter, and often changes accidentally - for instance a parent process `execs` itself incrementally with new input to avoid argument length issues. If it does not do a very thorough job of cleaning up after itself - which it needn't do for this very reason - all of its children are dumped on `init,` which will clean them up eventually. `namespaces` are simple, secure ways to avoid that kind of problem.

Answer (score 21):

If you know the parent processes PID you can do this using `pkill`.

#### Example

```
$ pkill -TERM -P 27888
```

Where the PPID is 27888.

*excerpt from pkill man*

```
   -P, --parent ppid,...
          Only match processes whose parent process ID is listed.
```

#### What's my PID in a script?

This is probably your next question so when in a Bash script you can find out the script's PID using `$$` at the top.

#### Example

Say I have this script:

```
$ more somescript.bash 
#!/bin/bash

echo "top: $$"
sleep 5
echo "bottom: $$"
```

Now I run it, backgrounded:

```
$ ./somescript.bash &
[2] 28007
top: 28007
```

Peeking at it with `pgrep` shows we've got the right PID:

```
$ pgrep somescript.bash
28007
$ bottom: 28007

[2]+  Done                    ./somescript.bash
```

#### Using a process' PGID

If you use this `ps` command you can find out a processes PGID, which you can kill using instead.

Using now this script, `killies.bash`:

```
$ more killies.bash 
#!/bin/bash

sleep 1000 &
sleep 1000 &
sleep 1000 &

sleep 100
```

We run it like so:

```
$ killies.bash &
```

Checking in on it:

```
$ ps x -o  "%p %r %c"
  PID  PGID COMMAND
28367 28367 killies.bash
28368 28367 sleep
28369 28367 sleep
28370 28367 sleep
28371 28367 sleep
```

Now we kill the PGID:

```
$ pkill -TERM -g 28367
[1]+  Terminated              ./killies.bash
```

#### Additional methods

If you take a look at this SO Q&A you'll find still more methods for doing what you want:

- [Best way to kill all child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes)

#### References

- [How does a Linux/Unix Bash script know its own PID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493642/how-does-a-linux-unix-bash-script-know-its-own-pid)

Comment: 1. Does this kill only immediate children, or _all_ descendents? 2. Does this address the issue where one of the intermediate descentends exits, breaking the link in the process tree?

Comment: This kills every process that's parent is your script.

Comment: This worked for me. This terminates the parent process and all its child processes.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is to use `systemd` (or another way using cgroups) for starting and stopping the application. A process can leave its process group but can never (at least not without root privilege) leave its cgroup. Thus `systemd` creates a new cgroup for the new process and later simply kills everything in the cgroup.

Comment: `namespaces` would be a more generalized solution. In that way you need only rely on in-kernel structures and not on some `init`'s implementation. You can also easily capture a process's pid at launch without relying on either regardless of its PPID, as I demonstrate in my own answer. http://lwn.net/Articles/531114/

Comment: @mikeserv cgroups are a pure in-kernel structure.

Comment: this is true. `systemd,` on the other hand, is not. I've only just now noticed the (or another...) part. If youll allow me I'll remove my comment, or if you prefer it can remain and we can all laugh at how stupid I am.

Comment: systemd is not killing all the cgroup process, can you please help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138221/cgroup-processes-not-terminated-even-when-main-process-has-been-killed-through-s

Comment: This question really needs an answer with instructions how to use plain cgroups to do this (without systemd).

Answer (score 2):

```
${PROC_CMD} &
pid=$!
kids=$(grep -l "PPid.*$$" /proc/*/status | grep -o "[0-9]*"
    for kid in $(cat /proc/$pid/task/*/children); do 
        kids="$kid $kids $(cat /proc/$kid/task/*/children)"
    done
    printf '%s ' $kids)
kill $kids
```

That kills all children of `${PROC_CMD},` which is backgrounded in the first line and its `$pid` captured in the next.

```
cat /proc/$pid/task/*/children
```

The above will just list the child processes.

It's important to remember that a process *can escape* its `$PPID.` For instance:

```
echo $( grep "Pid" /proc/self/status & )

Pid: 349 PPid: 1 TracerPid: 0
```

Comment: This misses all cases where a child dies before the grandchild.

Comment: @Gilles - thank you. I've alleviated that somewhat, but, still, the only sure way to handle this is with `namespaces` or some other kind of container. Or so I think, anyway.

Comment: @Gilles and now I think I also get all processes claiming the initial as the PPid. Probably it's redundant, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't see what your latest edits change. Suppose that P forks Q, then Q forks R, then Q exits, then your code runs. Nothing that you do will identify R as a descendant of P.

Comment: @Gilles - Agreed! Is there a solution here that handles that?

Comment: @Gilles The only way I can think to do it is something like my call to `$(grep)` at the bottom to do so at child process launch. At least, the only way without using a container of some kind. And even that only ensures I know about the children `$pids` - their children and so on could easily slip out.