# Reliable way to jail child processes using `nsenter:`

Tags: process, namespace

I know that Linux namespaces, among many other things, can be leveraged to handle restricting and jailing child processes securely without any chance of their being zombied and dumped on `init`. But I'm fuzzy on implementation details. How might I use the tools provided by `util-linux` such as `mount` and `nsenter` to watch, monitor, and ensure that all processes launched are the direct namespace descendants of another process?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Create a PID namespace

The correct command to use here is `unshare`. Note that the necessary options to do this are only available from `util-linux 2.23`. The idea is to create a new [PID namespace](https://lwn.net/Articles/531419/) for the program you are running such that all its children are also created in this namespace. You can run a command in a new PID namespace simply by doing:

```
sudo unshare -fp some_command
```

To run a shell, just omit the command. This will create a process which, along with any of its children, will have a PID as usual within the parent (system) namespace. However, within the new namespace, it will have a PID of `1` along with some of the special characteristics of the `init` process. Perhaps the most relevant characteristic from a monitoring perspective is that if a any of its descendants are orphaned, they will be re-parented to this process rather than the real `init` process.

Simply doing this may be enough for most monitoring cases. As previously mentioned, the processes within the namespace all have PIDs within the parent namespace so regular commands can be used to monitor their activity. We are also assured that if any process in the namespace becomes orphaned, it will not fall out of the process tree branches beneath the PID of the the top level program meaning that it can still easily be kept track of.

#### Combine with a mount namespace

However, what we can't do is monitor the process with respect to the PID that it *thinks* that is has. To do this, and in particular to be able to use the `ps` command within the new namespace, you need to mount a separate `procfs` filesystem for the namespace. This in turn leads to another problem since the only location that `ps` accepts for `procfs` is `/proc`. One solution would be to create a `chroot` jail and mount the new `procfs` there. But this is a cumbersome approach as at a minimum we would need to copy (or at least hard link) any binaries that we intend to use along with any libraries they depend on to the new root.

The solution is to also use a new *mount namespace*. Within this we can mount the new `procfs` in a way that uses the true root `/proc` directory, can be usable within PID namespace and doesn't interfere with anything else. To make this process very simple, the `unshare` command gives the `--mount-proc` option:

```
sudo unshare -fp --mount-proc some_command
```

Now running `ps` within the combined namespaces will show only the processes with the PID namspace and it will show the top level process as having a PID of `1`.

#### What about `nsenter`?

As the name suggests, `nsenter` can be used to enter a namespace that has already been created with `unshare`. This is useful if we want to get information only available from inside the namespace from an otherwise unrelated script. The simplest way is to access give the PID of any program running within the namespace. To be clear this must be the PID of the target program within the namespace from which `nsenter` is being run (since namespaces can be nested, it is possible for a single process to have many PIDs). To run a shell in the target PID/mount namespace, simply do:

```
sudo nsenter -t $PID -m -p
```

If this namespace is set up as above, `ps` will now list only processes within that namespace.

Comment: Thanks, Graeme. This has already answered the question and more. What actually got me asking was reading the notes from the procfs man page on the various files in /proc/pid/ns/\* which says: *"Bind mounting this file (see mount(2)) to somewhere else in the filesystem keeps the ... namespace of the process specified by pid alive even if all processes currently in the namespace terminate."* Hardly the same question, I know, but this is already so good I thought if you felt it was relevant you might want to add it in. http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc

Comment: This is covered in the last section [LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/532748/) (just search for bind mount). I'm not really sure the point of it though as it keeps the PID namespace alive but after the top level `init` style process dies, you can't create any more.

Comment: Yeah, im not too sure on the rest either. But with this answer and `man` and a weekend to myself i mean to get a little more familiar with it. Thanks again. Maybe it has more relevance in the `--user ` namespace.