# What's the purpose of the /proc/pid/mountinfo file?

Tags: linux, mount, process, proc

What's the purpose of the `/proc/pid/mountinfo` file (with *pid* being numerical process id)?

As far as I can see it reflects contents of the `/proc/mounts` file but with added information.

Also the file seems to stay the same for all processes: diff for two randomly chosen processes returns no output (`diff /proc/3833/mountinfo /proc/2349/mountinfo`)

Please note that I'm not asking what does it contain. From the definitions on the internet I see that 'This file contains information about mount points.'. I'm asking why is it present in every process directory? What is its purpose there?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) for information about files in `/proc`.

There is one such file per process because not all processes see the same mount points. [Chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) is a traditional Unix feature that makes it possible to restrict processes to a subtree of the filesystem tree. A chrooted process would not see mount points outside its root. Linux takes this further with [namespaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92177/kernel-namespaces-support): a process can compose its own view of the filesystem by grafting subtrees around.

For more information on mount namespaces, see [per process private file system mount points](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153665/per-process-private-file-system-mount-points) and [Michael Kerrisk's articles on namespaces on LWN](http://lwn.net/Articles/531114/).