# Virtual block device

Tags: block-device

I'm not sure what I should be googling or if FUSE does this (I suspect not). I'd like to create a virtual block device for which all forms of access, for example reads and writes, go directly to my app.

I know I can create a file be used as a block device by doing

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=~/test count=100k
```

then create a loopback to it using

```
losetup /dev/loop0 ~/test`
```

But I would like accesses going directly to my app instead of to a file. I hope this question is fairly clear.

Comment: you might use linux kernel namespaces to do a private mount. look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153666/52934) for a brief overview to see if it might meet your needs.

Comment: You can do it with NBD or FUSE, see [How to write a userspace linux block device driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266677/how-to-write-a-userspace-linux-block-device-driver)

Comment: @lemonsqueeze: So do I create a block device with FUSE? or do I create a file with a loopback? I'm going to look at FUSE this weekend for this

Comment: With FUSE you can create a filesystem that just exposes one file and answer read/writes to this file as you like. It'll look like a regular file from the outside, so will have to be mounted with `-o loop`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use NBD.  Using [nbdkit](https://github.com/libguestfs/nbdkit) you can even write virtual block devices in [shell script](https://github.com/libguestfs/nbdkit/blob/master/plugins/sh/nbdkit-sh-plugin.pod) or other scripting languages (although stick to C if you want the best performance).  [I gave a talk about this topic at FOSDEM 2019](https://fosdem.org/2019/schedule/event/nbdkit/) where I did a live demo writing a Linux kernel block device in shell script.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments one of the possible ways is NBD. [BUSE](https://github.com/acozzette/BUSE) might help you getting started with that. It actually uses a Unix socket, so it should be reasonably performant.

Comment: or maybe you can use iSCSI

Answer (score -1):

Aren't you looking for `mmap()`?

I'm not sure how you'd `mmap` without having an actual file backing it, however, but you might have an arbitrarily big, zeroed, file (see `falocate`, `truncate`) and `mmap()` it with flag `MAP_PRIVATE`, so that writes to it are visible to your application only, and not carried through to disk.

Comment: I think you completely missed the point of the question. OP is asking how to create a virtual block device, that can be accessed through a block-device inode (e.g. something you'd find in `/dev/…`, and do all the fops from userspace. – `mmap` is an entirely different thing. *Some* block devices do support mmap; others don't. Also you can `mmap` without a backing file (see `MAP_ANONYMOUS`; strictly speaking the kernel will create an anonymous file out of the I/O cache in-situ). But all of this is on the opposite end of what OP was asking for. -1

Comment: you're right, I assumed his root problem was "changes being written to disk"; thanks for the MAP_ANONYMOUS info