# List running processes without procfs

Tags: linux, process, proc

I'd like to list running process (like using `ps` or `top`), but there is no procfs mounted.

The procfs not being mounted is intentional, and is made to prevent malicious user to access systems informations.

Is there a way I could still list running process, or is that plain impossible ?

I'm running Linux 3.16.

Comment: The answer is OS-specific. What operating system are you asking about? Please edit your question (add an appropriate tag, at least).

Comment: @Celada Sorry, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ps` gets all his information from the mounted procfs, so without procfs there is no source to gain that information. The only option I see is to mount proc for the call of ps/top and then unmount it, that minimized the risk.

Comment: Ok, so it's not possible using a `ps`. But, could I do it with a syscall, for instance ?

Comment: The systemcalls ps or top use are simple read and open syscalls against the `/proc/PID/*` files. So there are no other systemcalls you could use.

Comment: If the application is able to mount `/proc` then there's no security to gain by not leaving it mounted all the time. Not that leaving it mounted all the time is risky, but mounting it on demand adds additional complexity and provides zero benefit — and adding complexity is never good for security. @blue112

Answer (score 4):

Not mounting procfs sounds like a mistake. It doesn't really improve security, and Linux is designed to have `/proc` mounted. In particular, as you've found, `/proc` is how you find information about processes (on Linux, `ps` is just a pretty-printer for information found under `/proc`).

If you have a good reason to prevent some applications from accessing `/proc`, run them in a [container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC) or a [namespace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153665/per-process-private-file-system-mount-points). Do mount `/proc` at the root, and leave it out of the namespace.

Comment: What is the real purpose of mounting /proc, if I don't require it ?

Comment: @blue112 You want to run `ps`, so you do require it.

Comment: My original question was : Is there a way to list processes without /proc mounted, not How to run ps ?

Comment: @blue112 Same difference, as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> The procfs not being mounted is intentional, and is made to prevent malicious user to access systems informations.

Not having procfs mounted is not the only possible way to achieve that.

You can mount procfs with `hidepid=2` option to make unprivileged user see their own processes only, which hides a lot of information about the system. See [`proc(5)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for details about this function.

To limit access to procfs further (as it contains information not about processes only, but also files like `cpuinfo`, `modules` etc, and `hidepid` doesn't hide these parts), you can specify restricted mode for a mountpoint, like 0711 or even 0700. Given that `/proc` owner is root, only root would be allowed to access procfs in the latter case. This means that you can use `ps`, `top`, `htop` etc, inspect `/proc/mdstat` for example but only when you logged in as root, and other users can't - they would face "permission denied" error when trying to access `/proc`.

Also I don't recommend leaving your system without procfs at all, as a lot of programs rely on it being mounted (not only `ps`).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/423580)