# List running hidden processes after libprocesshider

Tags: linux, security

I make a project in Python3 for Raspberry Pi 4
I use few cli applications that.
In ps/htop/top I wanted to hide the command line used on it due to some security concerns.
I tried libprocesshider and its hiding entire process from the process table.
And no /proc/ generated. This seems much better for our client.

But I couldn't check IsProcessRuning() to kill the previous instance and start a new one.
Is there any other clue to list the running process without /proc/ ?

Similar question is found here, but no proper answer yet.
[List running processes without procfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192384/list-running-processes-without-procfs)

libprocesshider
https://github.com/gianlucaborello/libprocesshider/blob/master/processhider.c
https://sysdig.com/blog/hiding-linux-processes-for-fun-and-profit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libprocesshider just loads special version of `readdir()`, which doesn't list specified entries in `/proc`. To list all enties you can:

- Bind mount *procfs* somewhere else and read process info from there.
- Load original versions of `readdir()` using `dlopen()`/`dlsym()`.
- Use `readdir` syscall directly. For reference see `readdir()` implementation from your libc.

Comment: Thanks Anton Leontive,
I will try your suggestions soon.

Comment: You are a Super Man !
>>Load original versions of readdir() 
This tip helped me with ctypes in python.
Thanks again...

Comment: Glad to hear it helps. You can accept an answer by click on big gray check button on its left side.

Comment: I think SE must improve its web gui.
Till now I couldn't search Accept button and Closed/Solved button on the page.

Comment: Ok finally I found the Accept button is the Tick mark icon.
Done !