# Restrict /proc/mounts to avoid exposure of /run/user/

Tags: systemd, selinux, tmpfs

**EDIT**: Currently looking at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153665/per-process-private-file-system-mount-points) solution.. (namespaces), but still wouldn't mind any pointers for doing what I'm after another way.

We have a custom SELinux policy on CentOS 7.2 which confines users to a restricted form of the user_u role.  Part of this disables the use of anything which accesses btmp/utmp/wtmp.  This is done without the use of a private mount namespace. We'd like to be able to restrict the visibility of other currently-logged-in users.

It's still possible to list the users on the system by doing a df:

```
tmpfs                              380M     0  380M   0% /run/user/3435
tmpfs                              380M     0  380M   0% /run/user/3434
```

*/proc/self/mounts* (the ultimate pointee starting from */etc/mtab*) will always list the system-wide mounts (again, this is without mount namespaces).  As an aside, (and in case at all relevant), we have */proc* mounted with the *hidepid=2* option.

**Question**: Does anyone know a way of restricting /run/user/... from ending up in */proc/self/mounts*?  Mount namespaces have not been ruled out yet, but we'd like to explore alternatives, too.

Comment: For virtual filesystems you're probably going to have a hard time with SELinux since it depends on tagging. [`pam_namespace`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_namespace) is probably your best bet (unless there's a systemd equivalent that I'm just not aware of).

Comment: TBH if you're this high security, you'll probably want to implement namespaces eventually. There are going to be other instances where they need some kind of `/tmp` but you don't want everyone sharing the same one.

Comment: Hi Bratchley - thanks for your reply.  We currently implement polyinstantiated namespacing for /tmp and /var/tmp via pam_namespace.  I thought it could also be appropriate for /run, but I now understand that each instance of /run/user/<uid> is precisely that - already it's own instance.  I suppose i'll need to just go ahead with a full-on namespace.