# Running HTTP process as a sole child in PID/NET namespace

Tags: apache-httpd, namespace, network-namespaces

First time posting here so I appreciate your help and patience. After reading about namespaces, looking on various forums including [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124162/reliable-way-to-jail-child-processes-using-nsenter) thread and trial and error I'm still looking for answers for a task (not a production implementation) I need to accomplish.

I need to create a namespace that has HTTP process as the only process running in it. If that HTTP process dies the namespace the HTTP process contained in should die too as this is the natural behaviour of namespaces (unless `bind-mount` is used). That should be achieved using the `unshare` command.

I tried various ways to achieve it and the best scenario I had the desired result for 5 seconds until the HTTP process contained in my PID namespace was dumped on the global `init` and thus killed the namespace it was in. I know this is apache default behaviour but why won't the main apache process stay attached to the `init` process inside the PID namespace?

I'm using Fedora 20 running `util-linux` 2.24.2 so `--fork` and `--mount-proc` options are supported.

**Update 1:** I have tried using *network namespace* but couldn't find a way to remain with only one process, httpd, as a child to the namespace.

Moving to *pid namespace*. I'm using

```
unshare –fp --mount-proc -- /usr/sbin/httpd –k start –DFOREGROUND
```

It works well for the first time. The httpd process runs as the only child of the namespace. When I kill the child the father is dead which is what I want. If I repeat the same command I start to see issues that are probably a result of `--mount-proc` option. Is there's anything I'm missing here with `--mount-proc` option usability?

Comment: At the point that you're trying to jail a particular application and confine it to a particular namespace you're talking about containers (aka LXC). You might want to look into `docker`.

Comment: [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/docker-explained-how-to-containerize-and-use-nginx-as-a-proxy) is a tutorial for Docker+nginx.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Joel. I'm aware of Docker but not sure it would serve me in what I need. My goal is to have a scenario in which one process only (httpd) running under a namespace and when this process dies the namespace dies too.