# CGroup Processes Not Terminated even when main process has been killed through Systemctl stop command

Tags: linux, process, systemd, cgroups

I am running `systemctl stop process` command for some process.

Please find the output for `systemctl status process` below:

```
Loaded: loaded
Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm)
CGroup: name=systemd:process
                  ├ 15768 process1
                  ├ 15769 process2
                  └ 15822 /bin/systemctl restart named.service
```

Even after running systemctl stop process, the status of Main Process remains "deactivating" only.

As per the default behavior, once the main process has exited, the processes in the cgroup should have been killed.

Can someone please provide some hint to resolve this issue.

Thanks