# Format 'ps' command output without whitespace

Tags: csv, ps

I have the following `ps` command to get particular properties of all the running processes along with some properties:

```
ps --no-headers -exo "uname,ppid,pid,etime,%cpu,%mem,args"
```

I wish to have it formatted in CSV so I can parse it. Note I have put the args at the end to make parsing easy; I don't think a `,` will exist in any of the other columns - please correct me if I am wrong.

How do I remove the whitespace?

Comment: Better answer + explanation = https://stackoverflow.com/a/54857780/128977 (in short, AIX formatting supports this, + workaround for memory value)

Answer (score 15):

From the man page:

```
-o format       user-defined format.
                format is a single argument in the form of a blank-separated or comma-separated list, which offers a
                way to specify individual output columns. The recognized keywords are described in the STANDARD FORMAT
                SPECIFIERS section below. Headers may be renamed (ps -o pid,ruser=RealUser -o comm=Command) as
                desired. If all column headers are empty (ps -o pid= -o comm=) then the header line will not be
                output. Column width will increase as needed for wide headers; this may be used to widen up columns
                such as WCHAN (ps -o pid,wchan=WIDE-WCHAN-COLUMN -o comm). Explicit width control
                (ps opid,wchan:42,cmd) is offered too. The behavior of ps -o pid=X,comm=Y varies with personality;
                output may be one column named "X,comm=Y" or two columns named "X" and "Y". Use multiple -o options
                when in doubt. Use the PS_FORMAT environment variable to specify a default as desired; DefSysV and
                DefBSD are macros that may be used to choose the default UNIX or BSD columns.
```

So try:

```
/bin/ps -o uname:1,ppid:1,pid:1
```

Comment: Would you mind selecting this as the Accepted Answer? @jeff-schaller

Comment: This doesn't output CSV. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54857780/128977 for CSV output directly from ps.

Comment: Where eactly does this work @Fel

Answer (score 6):

Since the first 6 fields should not contain blank characters (unless you allow them in user names), you can post-process the output:

```
ps --no-headers -exo "uname,ppid,pid,etime,%cpu,%mem,args" | sed '
  s/[\"]/\\&/g
  s/  */,/;s/  */,/;s/  */,/;s/  */,/;s/  */,/;s/  */,"/
  s/$/"/'
```

Here quoting the last field (args) after having escaped the `"`s and `\`s with `\`.

Produces an output like:

```
stephane,3641,3702,10-00:20:24,0.1,0.3,"some cmd,and,args... VAR=foo\"bar"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` with `ps`. So what you want is here:-

```
ps --no-headers -exo "uname,ppid,pid,etime,%cpu,%mem,args" | sed 's/\ /,/g'
```

But I wonder if it would be useful, as output of `ps` itself has got lots of `,`.

Comment: As I mentioned, I believe I have only chosen one column that could have a `,` which I have put at the end, however, this solution would remove the `,` from that column which I do not want.

Comment: Look at the output that generates and tell me if you think that's desirable :) Especially take notice of the command column.

Comment: That would be the same as `tr ' ' ,`. You probably want `tr -s ' ' ,` here.