# Why does unshare based killing only work reliably with --fork?

Tags: process, kill, namespace, unshare

From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124148/100270) we have learned that you can implement reliable killing of entire process subtrees with Linux PID namespaces via `unshare -p`.

Here is problem with it that I don't understand:

- It only works when I use the `-f`/`--fork` option to unshare.

  ```
  unshare -fp -- bash -c "watch /bin/sleep 10000 && echo hi"
  ```

  When I run this, and `kill -9` the PID of that `bash`, then watch, sleep etc are all dead, as I desire.
- But when I use it without `-f`:

  ```
  unshare -p -- bash -c "watch /bin/sleep 10000 && echo hi"
  ```

  and `kill -9` the bash PID, then the `watch` gets reparented to PID 1 (on my Ubuntu that's systemd), so I don't have the desired effect of killing all children.

**Questions:**

- Why is `--fork` necessary to get the desired effect? Why is `unshare` using `exec()` without fork not enough?
- Is there a workaround for this? I would prefer if I could conveniently send `kill -9` to the PID created by starting `unshare` to kill everything below it. But when I use `--fork`, killing the pid returned when I started `unshare` will, well, simply kill `unshare` and have `bash` reparented to PID 1, because `unshare` is not in my PID namespace.

---

<sub>Note, the `&& echo hi` is needed because if you give only one command to `bash -c`, it will `exec()` it and thus the bash process is gone (replaced) and you can't kill its PID.</sub>

Comment: Hmm, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45973522/263061) suggests that the effects of `-n` (`unshare(CLONE_NEWPID)`) only come into acction for the first child process forked. I _think_ that would explain my first question, but the question about what the best workaround is still stands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described [in this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45973522/263061) the effects of `-n` (`unshare(CLONE_NEWPID)`) only come into acction for the first child process forked.

In particular, [man 2 unshare](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unshare.2.html) says says about `CLONE_NEWPID`:

> Unshare the PID namespace, so that the calling process has a new PID namespace for its children which is not shared with any previously existing process.
>
> **The calling process is not moved into the new namespace.**
>
> **The first child created by the calling process** will have the process ID 1 and will assume the role of `init(1)` in the new namespace.

---

## Patching `unshare` to make killing work reliably

Since asking my question, in the last couple hours I've written a patch to `util-linux` ([pull request here](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/pull/511)) that adds a `--kill-child` flag to `unshare`.

**Edit:** This is now merged and released as part of util-linux `v2.32`.

You can use it like this:

```
unshare -fp --kill-child -- bash -c "watch /bin/sleep 10000 && echo hi"
```

and killing `unshare` will tear the entire process tree down as expeted.

#### Without `root`

You can even use it without `root` privileges if your kernel has user namespaces enabled (`CONFIG_USER_NS=y`) by passing the `-U` flag:

```
unshare -Ufp --kill-child -- bash -c "watch /bin/sleep 10000 && echo hi"
```