# Killing a process running executed with sudo without using sudo in kill command

Tags: bash, shell-script, kill, job-control

So I have a server, and I have access to sudo to do one thing only: run a single whitelisted script (I'll call it the target script). I do not have access to sudo anything else. Problem is, this script stops randomly, and someone needs to keep restarting it, which is annoying. I created the below script (I'll call this the babysitter script) to automate this. In short, it's running 2 parallel instances of the script simultaneously, and restarts them up to 5 times if they stop.

This is all well and good, except I now can't figure out a way to stop the target script. When I directly run it from the terminal, I can Ctrl+C to kill it. However, now that it's being started by the babysitter script, I can't figure out how to kill it. For example, say I want to put something at the bottom of the below script to kill both instances of the target script after they have run for 5 seconds.

I have tried various `kill` and `pkill` commands, but it seems there is no way to kill a sudo process without `kill`/`pkill` also running with sudo. As a workaround, I have been trying various ways of foregrounding the target scripts using `fg` so I can manually hit Ctrl+C, but I can't seem to figure out a way to foreground processes started within a bash script.

I have the ability to modify my babysitter script, but not the target script. Is there any way to kill the target script?

The babysitter script:

```
echo "ENTER YOUR PASSWORD:"
read -s PASSWORD  

COUNTOUTER=1
while [ $COUNTOUTER -le 2 ]; #Create 2 parallel processes
do
    (
        COUNTINNER=1
        while [ $COUNTINNER -le 5 ]; #Restart the target script up to 5 times 
        do
            echo $PASSWORD | exec sudo -S ./test.sh > process1.log & 
            wait $!
            ((COUNTINNER++))
        done
    )&
    ((COUNTOUTER++))
done

sleep 5

# I want to do something here to kill the target processes
```

Comment: 1. why get bash to read and then echo the password when `sudo` will prompt for your password when it needs it anyway?   2. if you don't have permission to run `pkill` or `kill` with sudo, ask your sysadmin to write you another wrapper script that kills only your "target" script and give you sudo access to it.

Comment: 1. bash reads password and pipes it into sudo because otherwise, someone will need to enter it every time the babysitter script restarts the child. This defeats the purpose of the babysitter, which is to automatically restart the target without human attention. 2. Sysadmin says any increased privileges involve approval from security and legal compliance teams, which will take a long time. I 'm looking for a short term workaround

Comment: 1. then talk to your sysadmin about getting NOPASSWD sudo access for that command. Putting your password onto a command line (even echo) makes it not only possible but easy for anyone else on your system to extract it by running `ps` or otherwise trawling the process list.  2. you don't have sudo access to kill, so there is no "short-term solution" - you're asking "how can I do something I can't do and know that I can't do?", and the answer is "you can't".

Comment: I don't like your script and don't use sudo, but if you can really kill your whitelisted script with ^C, then you could run it in a pseudo-tty; tearing down the pseudo-tty will cause it the _kernel_ to send it a SIGHUP signal, which should terminate it. Try it with `script /dev/null -c 'sudo ... your command ...'`. Killing the `script` process will also kill the privileged sudo which runs inside the pseudo-tty it has created.

Comment: @cas 1. Not to excuse storing (sensitive) passwords in plain text in scripts, but `echo` is a shell built-in; `echo "$PASSWORD" | ...` won't appear in any public `/proc/PID/cmdline`. 2. The inability to send a signal to a privileged process you have yourself started can be easily worked around, at least for HUP, INTR, QUIT and TSTP by running the process in a pseudo-tty.

Comment: @mosvy Great, if you submit that as an answer, I'll accept it. Though, I've been trying to test out the script command out locally on my macOS, but it seems it works differently on macOS (or maybe bash 3). `script /dev/null command "sudo ls"`, or nearly anything I type inside the quotations yields command not found. As a workaround, I'm saving my command in another file cmd.sh, and running `script /dev/null command "./cmd.sh"`. Just out of curiosity, do you know of a better, portable way to run a pseudo-tty without using a separate file? (If you don't it's fine, I can deal with different file)

Comment: @mosvy Regarding not liking my script, if you have suggestion for improvements within my constraints (no sudo, no asking sysadmin for increased privileges), I'm all ears

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but if the script(1) from MacOS is similar to that of that of FreeBSD, then `script /dev/null echo simple command`, `script /dev/null sh -c '...'` or `script /dev/null su root -c '...'` should work (the "command" in the synopsis is supposed to be the command you want to run, not the word "command" ;-)).

Comment: Also, you can answer your own Q with whatever works best for you, based or not on suggestions from the comments.

Comment: If someone is wondering why `script /dev/null command "./cmd.sh"` was kind of working, it's because on BSD there's a `/usr/bin/command` executable script which just runs `builtin command "$@"` ;-)