# killing parent process doesn't kill child

Tags: process, kill

I have a question.
Studying processes management I observed a strange behavior, on a CentOS 7.
I know that killing a parent process, the child processes are killed also. But not in the following case. I ran the command dd, just for example:

```
[root@server2 ~]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null &
[1] 1756

[root@server2 ~]# ps fax | grep -B2 dd
1737 pts/2    S      0:00         \_ su -
1741 pts/2    S      0:00             \_ -bash
1756 pts/2    R      1:18                 \_ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
```

After that I tried to kill (with SIGKILL signal) the parent process, that is the bash, but this action doesn't kill the dd process:

```
[root@server2 ~]# kill -9 1741
Killed
[user@server2 ~]#
```

The shell terminates but as you can see in the top command output, the dd process is still working:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
1756 root      20   0  107948    612    512 R 99.9  0.1  10:06.98 dd
```

Do you have any idea about it please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default killing a parent process does not kill the children processes.

I suggest you look for other questions about how to kill both the parent and child using the process group (a negative PID).

A good answer about how to do this in detail can be found at [Process descendants](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14815/process-descendants)

Answer (score 1):

Please adjust to your own needs, especially on the kill command:

```bash
function kill_recurse() {
    cpids=`pgrep -P $1|xargs`
    for cpid in $cpids;
    do
        kill_recurse $cpid
    done
    echo "killing $1"
    kill -9 $1
}
```

Example usage would be: `kill_recurse <my_parent_pid>`

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation and found the answer.

## TLDR;

try: `kill -2 <parent_pid>`

You will know if this method will work for you, if while running your script and you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would kill the parent and all spawned processes.

The reason for this is the different signals that `kill` can send. By default `kill <pid>` will send `15 <SIGTERM>` signal. But the regular signal when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is not `15 <SIGTERM>` it is in fact `2 <SIGINT>`.

So if you `kill -2 <pid>` this will kill your parent process as if having interrupted it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

[source](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0100.php)

Comment: I don't think this is quite correct. Ctrl-C kills all the processes because the of [terminal magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64781302/265521). `kill -2` will still only send it to one process.