# Bash script should only kill those instances of another script's that it has launched

Tags: bash, process

In the current situation, a certain script 'calling.sh' launches another script 'called.sh' in the background, performs other operations, sleeps for a while, and then terminates 'called.sh' with a `pkill called.sh`. This works fine.

Then, I would also like to launch 'called.sh' from other terminals *as a standalone script* at any other time, whether before or after launching calling.sh. These independent instances *should not* be killed by 'calling.sh'.

How can I achieve this? Intuition says that the calling script should be able to tell the process it started from any other namesakes that are running in the meantime.

As a variant, 'calling.sh' may also launch 'called' which is a *symbolic link* to 'called.sh'. Does this complicate managing the above situation? Which specific cautions and adjustments does using a symbolic link require?

Comment: I believe unshare is specifically for this:   https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/450242/323121

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Don't use the name to kill it. Since the `calling.sh` script is calling the process you later want to kill, just use `$!` (from `man bash`):

> **`!`**
>   Expands  to the process ID of the job most recently placed
>   into the background, whether executed as an  asynchronous  command  or  using  the  `bg` builtin

So, if you're `calling.sh` is like this:

```
called.sh &
## do stuff
pkill called.sh
```

Change it to this:

```
called.sh &
calledPid=$!
# do stuff
kill "$calledPid"
```

Comment: This should work as long as called.sh does not die by itself, because otherwise its pid might be reused, killing an innocent and unrelated process as a result.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev that's a very good point. I guess you could also check that the `$calledPid`'s parent PID is the PID of `called.sh`.

Comment: To reinforce the answer, this is another resource I found useful to organize my thoughts: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement

Answer (score 18):

I've had to pick this but out of scripts so many times; it's even more fun when the scripts are called as part of a complex automated schedule.  You really shouldn't rely on something like `pkill` to select which script to kill.

Inside of calling.sh you should record the PIDs of the jobs you have started and kill them explicitly by PID.

Inside calling.sh:

```
./called.sh &
called_pid=$!

# Later
kill $called_pid
```