# When do you need 'nohup' if you're already forking using '&'?

Tags: shell, nohup, fork

First this question is related but definitely not the same as this very nice question:

[Difference between nohup, disown and &](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and)

I want to understand something: when I do '&', I'm forking right?

Is it ever useful to do "nohup ... &" or is simply & sufficient?

Could someone show a case where you'd be using '&' and still would want to use 'nohup'?

Comment: Have you read the accepted answer and its comment thread? They do explain what `nohup` does. What part has you confused?

Comment: @Gilles: it may be obvious to **you**, because you happen to be familiar with these things (seen your rep)...  However, for a start, the accepted answer in the link I did put to **does not say a word** about using both *nohup* and '&'...  I'm pretty sure my question is clear enough and different enough from the other, and two great answers here seems to prove that ; )   Also, are you really implying I did took the pain to link to another question, but without reading the accepted answer!?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First of all, every time you execute a command, you shell will fork a new process, regardless of whether you run it with `&` or not. `&` only means you're running it in the background.

<sub>*Note this is not very accurate. Some commands, like `cd` are shell functions and will usually not fork a new process. `type cmd` will usually tell you whether `cmd` is an external command or a shell function. `type type` tells you that `type` itself is a shell function.*</sub>

`nohup` is something different. It tells the new process to ignore `SIGHUP`. It is the signal sent by the kernel when the parent shell is closed.

To answer your question do the following:

1. run `emacs &` *(by default should run in a separate X window)*.
2. on the parent shell, run `exit`.

You'll notice that the `emacs` window is killed, despite running in the background. This is the default behavior and `nohup` is used precisely to modify that.

Running a job in the background (with `&` or `bg`, I bet other shells have other syntaxes as well) is a shell feature, stemming from the ability of modern systems to multitask. Instead of forking a new shell instance for every program you want to launch, modern shells (`bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`, ...) will have the ability to manage a list of programs (or **jobs**). Only one of them at a time can be at the *foreground*, meaning it gets the shell focus. I wish someone could expand more on the differences between a process running in the foreground and one in the background (the main one being acess to `stdin`/`stdout`).

In any case, this does not affect the way the child process reacts to `SIGHUP`. `nohup` does.

Comment: +1 to both of you for the great answers...   But I'm still confused... I tried that before answering my question: maybe my (very old) Debian Linux setup isn't correctly configured but if I "emacs &" and then type "exit", only my xterm exits: emacs stays there.

Comment: Emacs is complicated enough that it may handle SIGHUP on its own. It's only by default that processes exit on SIGHUP.  A lot of 'daemon' programs like ntpd or inetd will re-read their configuration on SIGHUP instead of exiting.  I'm a vim guy myself, so I don't have much experience with any emacs.

Comment: There's nothing special about emacs.  A shell typically sends `SIGHUP` to its child processes when the shell itself receives `SIGHUP`, not when the shell exits normally.  bash has an option `huponexit` that causes it to send `SIGHUP` to children when it exits, but it's not enabled by default.  http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Signals

Comment: hello. first of all, great explanation. I tried to verify your thesis by running a process with `&` and closed my shell by running `exit`. The process is still running. Any ideas on why it hasnt been killed? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: What's the process you're running?

Comment: @rahmu I created a simple script in Python that creates a file every second for 60 seconds (dumb way to really see whether the script is running or not). I opened the terminal, run the script with `&` and then run the `exit` command. The terminal window has closed but the script has continued to create the files, ie. "was still running"... ?

Answer (score 21):

Is it ever useful to do `nohup ... &`? Yes. If you just start a process "in the background" with `&`, that new process still has membership in the original shell's "process group".  If that shell or the process group gets certain signals (SIGHUP, for example), by default they exit.  This means that if you run a process with `&` from a shell started by an xterm, or rxvt or some other windowing terminal emulator, when you close the window, the background process gets a SIGHUP.  Most casually-written code does not handle SIGHUP, and therefore exits.

If you do `nohup ... &`, the `nohup` command sets SIGHUP to ignored, and then execs the command.  That newly exec'ed command keeps the signal mask that `nohup` setup, unless the command does some signal handling itself. If you close the xterm or rxvt or whatever, the kernel delivers SIGHUP to the command's process, which is ignored.  It keeps running.

Doing a `nohup` on a command allows it to keep running after you close the xterm, or you log off.

Comment: Sorry - you lost me.  Are you saying that using `&` with `nohup` keeps the command running in certain instances where only using `nohup` wouldn't?  That seems to conflict with the answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288064/1822

Comment: @MikeB - The "&" does the usual fork/set things/exec system calls to put the command "in the background". That is, the command that gets nohupped is running asynchronously. The `nohup` does some things before the `exec()` system call to make the forked process ignore certain signals. So, yes, an "&" will allow a command to run under certain circumstances that a plain old `nohup` would not. Like closing the xterm associated with the shell that did the nohup, or logging off.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I don't see mentioned here, the "send HUP on terminal exit" event is configurable - it may or may not happen. This may be confusing some peoples' perception of how `nohup` is working. If sending HUP on terminal exit has been disabled, they will come to the conclusion `nohup` is not needed. Sending HUP on terminal exit is a shell option in bash.

Try

```
shopt | grep huponexit
```

This will tell you if HUP is even being sent on terminal exit.  If it is, you will need to use nohup.  If it is not, you won't.

Comment: bash will send a HUP signal to its jobs --even when huponexit is off, which is the default-- if bash itself is signaled with with a HUP (which happens when the terminal it runs in is torn down). See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/568332/308316).

Comment: tl;dr; this answer is wrong: You DO need `nohup` even when `huponexit` is off, and `nohup` may no longer be _enough_ (because of `systemd` and `KillUserProcesses`)

Answer (score -1):

if you run a program in the background ( with & as a suffix ) on linux operating system and logout even after that  it will keep running:  try out with:

```
  ping google.com > ping_result  &
```

After login back check the number of lines in the output file `ping_result` that will keep increasing means it is still running however it has been told that it will be closed. then what is the use of `nohup` command .

another scenario ==> as stated above for `nohup emac &` --> that should keep `emac` running after system logout but  it doesn't show running after login back .