# What happens if I don't use & at the end of a nohup command?

Tags: centos, nohup

What's the difference between `nohup foocommand` and `nohup foocommand &`?

I understand that `&` marks the task/job/process as running in the background but does that make it more resilient than it would otherwise be?

What happens in both scenarios if my SSH session timeouts or if I get disconnected?

Comment: But of course, see also [What are the shell’s control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408)

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is that the second form put your task into background immediately.

In both cases the process would not terminate if your `ssh` session get disconnected