# Why are processes run with nohup in rc.local killed?

Tags: linux, nohup

I have the following script under **raspbian jessie**:

file `test.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
nohup sleep 321 &
sleep 120
false
exit 0
```

When run as normal user in a terminal session, I have the following situation:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps -ejf |grep sleep
pi        5073  5072  5072  4618  0 15:16 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 321
pi        5074  5072  5072  4618  0 15:16 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 120
```

and after the script exits, the `sleep 321` process is reparented and still running as expected.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps -ejf |grep sleep
pi        5073     1  5072  4618  0 15:16 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 321
```

Why doesn't this work in `rc.local`? The command run with `nohup` gets just killed.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps -ejf |grep sleep
root       450   449   449   449  0 15:45 ?        00:00:00 sleep 321
root       451   449   449   449  0 15:45 ?        00:00:00 sleep 120
```

and after 120 seconds the `sleep 321` process just disappears.

It only works in `rc.local` when I replace `false` with `false || true`, so my guess is, it has something to do with running the script with `-e`, but why the difference between running `test.sh` from a terminal and `rc.local` at boot?

Answer (score 1):

Because `nohup` would allow only for `SIGHUP` ignore. But there's also "session" concept in UNIX processes; typical way to daemonize a process is somewhat way more lengthy than just ignoring SIGHUPs.

As [Gene Pavlovsky](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/165149/gene-pavlovsky) suggests in his [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266565/daemonize-a-process-in-shell/278157#comment483587_278157): "Take a look at [`daemonize`](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/). Besides a nice tool, it has pretty good explanations on what a daemon is."

— You should indeed.