# Order between `nohup`, `&` and redirection?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, background-process, nohup

What is the correct order between `nohup`, `&` and redirection, when using together?

Why are other orders not correct?

For example,

```
$ nohup firefox& &> /dev/null

$ nohup firefox &> /dev/null  &
```

and I don't know how to change the order between nohup with redirection and `&`.

Another example,

```
$ nohup sleep 1000 & &>/dev/null
```

doesn't redirect to `/dev/null`, but still to `./nohup.out`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start with section **SHELL GRAMMAR** from manual page for `bash`:

> **Simple Commands**
>
> A  *simple command* is a sequence of optional variable assignments followed by blank-separated words and *redirections*, and terminated by a *control operator*.

Therefore *redirection* (`&>/dev/null`) goes first and the *control operator* follows (`&`).

**Edit:** And to make the answer complete, the `nohup` is the first part of the *simple command*. It does not have any special meaning in `bash`.

Exactly your example (except the `/dev/null` which only makes it complicated):

```
jakuje@E6430:/tmp$ rm nohup.out out
jakuje@E6430:/tmp$ nohup sleep 1 & &>out
[1] 10876
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
[1]+  Done                    nohup sleep 1
jakuje@E6430:/tmp$ cat nohup.out             # empty
jakuje@E6430:/tmp$ cat out                   # empty
jakuje@E6430:/tmp$ rm nohup.out
jakuje@E6430:/tmp$ nohup sleep 1 &>out &
[1] 10882
[1]+  Done                    nohup sleep 1 &> out
jakuje@E6430:/tmp$ cat nohup.out             # no file
cat: nohup.out: No such file or directory
jakuje@E6430:/tmp$ cat out                   # output of nohup
nohup: ignoring input
```

Comment: do you mean only `nohup firefox &> /dev/null  &` is correct?

Comment: yes. As you write.

Comment: http://linuxg.net/how-to-transform-a-process-into-a-daemon-in-linux-unix/ says `nohup firefox& &> /dev/null`. So the webpage isn't correct?

Comment: You can't believe everything what is written on the Internet. It redirects to `/dev/null` so it does not matter much. Sorry, but giving it a try would not hurt, would it? See my example. The first one redirects the output of immediately backgrounded process, which is empty (but you get the output in `nohup.out`). The second one redirects the actual output of the command, in which you are interested.

Comment: Didn't I mention I have tried in my post?

Comment: Never mind. You are welcome (added exactly your example transcript. Sleep does not have any output, so it is not ideal example, but I hope you understand the behaviour better now).

Answer (score 1):

The `nohup` command is the command you are actually running in this case.  The word `firefox` is not interpreted *by the shell* as a command; it is simply passed as an argument to `nohup`.  What the `nohup` command does with that argument is "none of the shell's business".

Of course what `nohup` does is to take that argument and runs it as a command.

The point is that **what you're actually doing from the shell's point of view is redirecting the output of `nohup`, *not* the output of `firefox`.**

However, `nohup` will do different things with the output of the command that it runs, depending on where its own output is pointed.  From the [POSIX specs for `nohup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nohup.html) (emphasis added):

> **If the standard output is a terminal**, all output written by the named *utility* to its standard output shall be appended to the end of the file nohup.out in the current directory. If nohup.out cannot be created or opened for appending, the output shall be appended to the end of the file nohup.out in the directory specified by the HOME environment variable.  ...
>
> If standard error is a terminal and **standard output is open but is not a terminal**, all output written by the named utility to its standard error shall be redirected to the same open file description as the standard output.  ...

So due to some inner magic of `nohup`, your redirections work as expected if you run:

```
nohup utility >/dev/null &
```

Note that you don't need to redirect both `stderr` and `stdout`, as the `nohup` command will redirect the `stderr` of *utility* depending on where `nohup`'s own output is pointing to.  (Not to mention that `&>` isn't portable.)

There is also a portability issue with your input.  Since your `stdin` is connected to your terminal, it is implementation-specific what will happen with it.  (See [note under "Rationale" in the `nohup` POSIX specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nohup.html#tag_20_87_18).)  Instead you might be better off using:

```
nohup firefox >/dev/null </dev/null &
```

And as already mentioned in comments, there is no circumstance with `nohup` or any other command where you should ever put a redirection after the backgrounding `&`.

Comment: Thanks. From my experiement, both stdout and stderr for `nohup`  need to be redirected, so that there will be no `nohup.out` file created.

Comment: @Tim, what distribution are you using and what version of `nohup`?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 and nohup (GNU coreutils) 8.25