# How to run the follow sample in own process or processes?

Tags: bash, process, nohup

The Environment is a Linux like Debian or Ubuntu.

I have two examples; one is working fine, the other is not. How can I fix the non working one?

**First example:**

Here, I run commands in a terminal to launch another process. If I then close the terminal, the started `xed` process isn't killed:

```
var=xed
# start the xed
nohup "$var" &
```

I now close the terminal window and `xed` isn't killed. This is what I want to have happen.

**2nd example:**

In this example, I am also launching  second command from the terminal. However, in this case, closing the terminal window also kills the launched process of the portable Tor browser:

Open terminal window and type (thanks to terdon for the simpler way to call this):

```
var='/home/user/Schreibtisch/Tor/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser'
# start the portable Tor browser
nohup "$var" &
```

If I now close the terminal window, the portable Tor browser process crashes. That suggests to me that the Tor process or the Tor processes are not, or are not all, standalone in this case.

Perhaps the following links can give a hint:

- [Why is chromium-browser killed when I close the terminal despite nohup?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162749/why-is-chromium-browser-killed-when-i-close-the-terminal-despite-nohup)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421810/nohup-doesnt-work-with-chromium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The follow solution works for me from terminal, a dont work on .sh script:

```
cd /home/user/Schreibtisch/Tor/tor-browser_en-US
var='./Browser/start-tor-browser'
# start the portable Tor browser
nohup "$var" & disown
```

The follow don't work (the browser crash if the terminal will closed):

```
var='/home/user/Schreibtisch/Tor/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser'
# start the portable Tor browser
nohup "$var" & disown
```

Follow use "nohup":

Step1:
open Terminal and type:

```
var='/home/user/Schreibtisch/Tor/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser'
# start the portable Tor browser
nohup "$var" &
```

Step2:
Type on same terminal:

```
nohup xed &
```

Step3:
Close the terminal.
That don't crash anything above.