# Can someone explain in detail what "set -m" does?

Tags: linux, job-control

On the [man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html), it just says:

> -m  Job control is enabled.

But what does this actually mean?

I came across this command in a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156111/fabric-start-tomcat-remotely), I have the same problem as OP, which is "fabric cannot start tomcat". And `set -m` solved this. The OP explained a little, but I don't quite understand:

> The issue was in background tasks as they will be killed when the
> command ends.
>
> The solution is simple: just add "set -m;" prefix before command.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Quoting the bash documentation (from `man bash`):

```
JOB CONTROL
       Job  control  refers to  the  ability  to selectively  stop
       (suspend) the execution of  processes and continue (resume)
       their execution at a later point.  A user typically employs
       this facility via an interactive interface supplied jointly
       by the operating system kernel's terminal driver and bash.
```

So, quite simply said, having `set -m` (the default for
interactive shells) allows one to use built-ins such as `fg` and `bg`,
which would be disabled under `set +m` (the default for non-interactive shells).

It's not obvious to me what the connection is between job control and
killing background processes on exit, however, but I can confirm that
there is one: running `set -m; (sleep 10 ; touch control-on) &` will
create the file if one quits the shell right after typing that
command, but `set +m; (sleep 10 ; touch control-off) &` will not.

I think the answer lies in the rest of the documentation for `set -m`:

```
-m      Monitor  mode. [...]                     Background pro‐
        cesses run in a separate process group and a  line  con‐
        taining  their exit status is printed upon their comple‐
        tion.
```

This means that background jobs started under `set +m` are not actual
"background processes" ("Background processes are those whose process
group ID differs from the terminal's"): they share the same process
group ID as the shell that started them, rather than having their own
process group like proper background processes. This explains the
behavior observed when the shell quits before some of its background
jobs: if I understand correctly, when quitting, a signal is sent to
the processes in the same process group as the shell (thus killing
background jobs started under `set +m`), but not to those of other
process groups (thus leaving alone true background processes started
under `set -m`).

So, in your case, the `startup.sh` script presumably starts a
background job. When this script is run non-interactively, such as
over SSH as in the question you linked to, job control is disabled,
the "background" job shares the process group of the remote shell, and
is thus killed as soon that shell exits. Conversely, by enabling job
control in that shell, the background job acquires its own process
group, and isn't killed when its parent shell exits.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but how is `tomcat/bin/startup.sh` related to `fg`/`bg`?

Comment: It's not directly related; I was trying to answer "Job control is enabled / what does this actually mean?" in a general way. Perhaps I haven't made it clear, but your script appears to start a background job, which is what the rest of my answer applies to.

Answer (score 2):

I'v found this at github issue list, and I think this really answer your question.

> It's not really a SSH problem, it's more the subtle behaviour around
>   BASH non-interactive/interactive modes and signal propagation to
>   process groups.
>
> Following is based on 
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679178/why-does-ssh-wait-for-my-subshells-without-t-and-kill-them-with-t/14866774#14866774
>   and http://www.itp.uzh.ch/~dpotter/howto/daemonize, with some
>   assumptions not fully validated, but tests about how this works seem
>   to confirm.
>
> **pty/tty = false**
>
> The bash shell launched connects to the stdout/stderr/stdin of the
>   started process and is kept running until there is nothing attached to
>   the sockets and it's children have exited. A good deamon process will
>   ensure it doesn't wait for it's children to exit, fork a child process
>   and then exit. When in this mode no SIGHUP will be sent to the child
>   process by SSH. I believe this will work correctly for most scripts
>   executing a process that handles deamonizing itself and doesn't need
>   to be backgrounded. Where init scripts use '&' to background a process
>   then it's likely that the main problem will be whether the
>   backgrounded process ever attempts to read from stdin since that will
>   trigger a SIGHUP if the session has been terminated.
>
> **pty/tty = true***
>
> If the init script backgrounds the process started, the parent BASH
>   shell will return an exit code to the SSH connection, which will in
>   turn look to exit immediately since it isn't waiting on a child
>   process to terminate and isn't blocked on stdout/stderr/stdin. This
>   will cause a SIGHUP to be sent to the parent bash shell process group,
>   which since job control is disabled in non-interactive mode in bash,
>   will include the child processes just launched. Where a daemon process
>   explicitly starts a new process session when forking or in the forked
>   process then it or it's children won't receive the SIGHUP from the
>   BASH parent process exiting. Note this is different from suspended
>   jobs which will see a SIGTERM. I suspect the problems around this only
>   working sometimes has to do with a slight race condition. If you look
>   at the standard approach to deamonizing -
>   http://www.itp.uzh.ch/~dpotter/howto/daemonize, you'll see that in the
>   code the new session is created by the forked process which may not be
>   run before the parent exits, thus resulting the random sucess/failure
>   behaviour mentioned above. A sleep statement will allow enough time
>   for the forked process to have created a new session, which is why it
>   works for some cases.
>
> **pty/tty = true and job control is explicitly enabled in bash**
>
> SSH won't connect to the stdout/stderr/stdin of the bash shell or any
>   launched child processes, which will mean it will exit as soon as the
>   parent bash shell started finished executing the requested commands.
>   In this case, with job control explicitly enabled, any processes
>   launched by the bash shell with '&' to background them will be placed
>   into a separate session immediately and will not receive the SIGHUP
>   signal when the the parent process to the BASH session exits (SSH
>   connection in this case).
>
> **What's needed to fix**
>
> I think the solutions just need to be explicitly mentioned in the
>   run/sudo operations documentation as a special case when working with
>   background processes/services. Basically either use 'pty=false', or
>   where that is not possible, explicitly enable job control as the first
>   command, and the behaviour will be correct.

From https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/395