# Why fg command within an infinite while loop works like a "keep alive" watchdog?

Tags: background-process, webserver, autostart, watchdog

Recently, I've run into this implementation of a handicraft "keepalive" watchdog for a custom HTTP server:

```
|
|   keepalive.sh
|   init.sh
|_  main.py
```

There are three files. The first one being `keepalive.sh`: it is run as `root` from `rc.local` when the system starts up.

```bsh
# keepalive.sh

while true
do
    if curl -s "localhost:8080/alive.txt" | grep -q "ALIVE"; then
        echo "UP
    else
        echo "Restarting..."
        pkill -u www-data -SIGKILL
    fi
    sleep 30
done
```

The second one is `init.sh` which is run as `www-data` user.

```bsh
# init.sh

set -m
/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/main.py &
while true; do fg; sleep 1; done
```

The third one is the custom server itself `main.py` which needs to be kept alive.

```py
from server import Server

HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 8080

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Server(HOST,PORT).listen()
```

I don't quite understand how `init.sh` works. With `-m` flag we enable [job control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196603/can-someone-explain-in-detail-what-set-m-does) in order to use `fg` from script file. What is the purpose of sending `main.py` to background and then doing `fg` in an infinite `while`? I understand that `&` is needed here to get to the loop after the server was started but why exactly `fg` (and not just `true`, for example) is used?

The other thing I do not understand is why `init.sh` restarts when it is killed with `-SIGKILL`. The Python script is launched in a separate process group with `init.sh`'s PID as its own PPID. `main.py` gets killed when his parent (`init.sh`) gets killed, I'm all right with that. For me the question is why `init.sh` keeps restarting `main.py` (and also itself) after it's being killed with `pkill`.

Thanks!

Comment: `init.sh` doesn't make sense to me.  It starts `python` in the background, then immediately goes into the `while` loop which foregrounds the `python` process.  At that point, the loop blocks at the `fg`; the `sleep` will execute only after the `python` process terminates.  Then it loops again and there's no job in the background, so `fg` will fail, it will sleep again, and that will continue forever.

Comment: That’s the point. I don’t get it either.