# Shell script - child - background process

Tags: shell-script, scripting, background-process

I have the following situation :

As root `Script_A.sh` is run on the server and sleeps until triggered.
When triggered, it calls `Script_B.sh`, which loops on the server to determine which actions it needs to perform. Once it generates its list of actions, it will submit `Script_C.sh` as the process owner (`su - $sUser -c "/path/to/correct/script.sh"`).

My problem: is there a way to run the `su - $sUser -c "/path/to/correct/script.sh"` in background? I do not want to run the 3rd script sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me to just put `&` at the end as usual:

```
su - "$sUser" -c "/path/to/script.sh" &
```

If that doesn't work for you you'll need to edit your question to include more details about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Appending an `&` to the command is the way to run a command in the background. So:

```
su - $sUser -c "/path/to/correct/script.sh" &
```

Or if you want to make sure the script won't receive a SIGHUP (hang up signal) from script B use `disown`

```
su - $sUser -c "/path/to/correct/script.sh" & disown
```

I'm not 100% sure that this is going to have the exact effect that you need, as there may be side-effects from using `su`.
The `nohup` command is also useful for this type of endeavour, as it stops any output to the terminal, but it depends on your particular circumstances.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148698/83684) has more clarification on the use of `&`, `disown` and `nohup`.