# how to spawn a separate process in the background while running a foreground process

Tags: shell, osx, python

e.g., I want run a python -m HTTPSimpleServer in the background while running a watch in the background

> python -m HTTPSimpleServer; watch -n (my awesome test command)

how can I run both in parallel spawning from one command.

Comment: Can you spawn and make it the **same** process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
python -m HTTPSimpleServer &  # Your Python process will now be in the background
serverpid="$!"                # Capture its PID so that you can kill it later.
watch -n /path/to/AwesomeTestCommand Arg1 Arg2
# Some time later...
kill "$serverpid"             # Make your Python process go away
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
python -m HTTPSimpleServer & watch -n
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like replacing the ; with & ought to do the job.  Add another & at the end to put both programs in the background.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like a reply to an old post, but you can simply run the application in nohup

```
nohup python -m HTTPSimpleServer & watch -n
```

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/117549