# Terminal that is set to close .. takes the disowned gui_app with itself

Tags: shell, terminal, background-process, disown

a new terminal opens up and runs the script.

```
terminal -e "/script"
```

script runs a gui_app, disowns it. 
sleeps 4 seconds.

```
  #!/bin/sh

  /gui_app & disown

  sleep 4
```

after sleep.. terminal closes because there never was

```
   ;bash
```

attached to the command.

Conflict : it also shuts down the disowned gui_app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Difference between nohup, disown and &](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and#148698)

Try using nohup rather than disown:

```
nohup /gui_app &
```

Note that this will feed output into a file, `nohup.out`. To prevent this send `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`:

```
nohup /gui_app >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```