# (bash) Script A, wait for script B, but not its child process

Tags: bash, ssh, background-process

So I have scriptA which does:

```
ssh server1 -- scriptB &
ssh server2 -- scriptB &
ssh server3 -- scriptB &
wait
otherstuffhappens
```

ScriptB does:

```
rsync -av /important/stuff/. remoteserver:/remote/dir/.
rsync -av /not/so/important/stuff/. remoteserver:/remote/dir/. &
exit
```

My desired result is scriptA will wait for all the instances of scriptB to finish before moving on, which it currently does, however it's also waiting for the background rsyncs of the not so important stuff. These are larger files that I don't want to wait on.

I've read through [Difference between nohup, disown and &](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and?newreg=7d90868c862743ef9ad5997c3150bde0) and tried different combinations, but I'm not getting the result I'm looking for.

At this point I'm pretty stumped. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem here is that `sshd` waits for end-of-file on the pipe it is reading the command's stdout (not the stderr one for some reason, at least with the version I'm testing on) from. And the background job inherits a fd to that pipe.

So, to work around that, redirect the output of that background `rsync` command to some file or `/dev/null` if you don't care for it. You should also redirect stderr, because even if sshd is not waiting for the corresponding pipe, after `sshd` exits, the pipe will be broken so `rsync` would be killed if it tries to write on stderr.

So:

```
rsync ... > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Compare:

```
$ time ssh localhost 'sleep 2 &'
ssh localhost 'sleep 2 &'  0.05s user 0.00s system 2% cpu 2.365 total
$ time ssh localhost 'sleep 2 > /dev/null &'
ssh localhost 'sleep 2 > /dev/null &'  0.04s user 0.00s system 12% cpu 0.349 total
```

And:

```
$ ssh localhost '(sleep 1; ls /x; echo "$?" > out) > /dev/null &'; sleep 2; cat out
141  # ls by killed with SIGPIPE upon writing the error message
$ ssh localhost '(sleep 1; ls /x; echo "$?" > out) > /dev/null 2>&1 &'; sleep 2; cat out
2    # ls exited normally after writing the error on /dev/null instead
     # of a broken pipe
```

Answer (score 4):

Write a script which is the parent of both, then you can easily [control both](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement). Alternatively [establish a communications channel between the two channels](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/027).

To specifically ignore certain background jobs you can capture the PID (`$!` is the last backgrounded job PID) and `wait $pid` to wait only for that job to complete.

Answer (score 3):

The `-f` flag to `ssh` fixes the problem. Tested on:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
echo $$_script__begin
( echo sleeping; sleep 2; echo slept )&
echo $$_script__end
```

When I run it with `ssh localhost ./script`, it waits until `slept` shows up. With the `-f` flag, it exits at `echo $$_script__end` and `slept` later shows up in the background after the `ssh` command has returned.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem of OpenSSH server, that is described and discussed in upstream [bugzilla #2071](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2071). In the bug, there are proposed several workarounds either in the OpenSSH side, but also for the script.

If you want to wait for the output of the scripts, you should add a `wait` before `exit` of the `scriptB` too.

If you don't care about the output, use some variation of `nohup` and IO redirection to `/dev/null`, which will resolve the problem same way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.`$!` is default shell variable that contains the process ID of the most recently executed background pipeline/process.

```
command1 &
lpid1=$!

command2 &
lpid2=$!

command3 &
lpid=$!

wait $lpid1  # waits for only the process with PID lpid1  to complete.
```

You need to utilize this as per your script by using `export` variable etc

Answer (score 1):

B just needs to wait for it's own background processes:

```
rsync -av /important/stuff/. remoteserver:/remote/dir/.
rsync -av /not/so/important/stuff/. remoteserver:/remote/dir/. &
wait
exit
```

Comment: At that point you might as well just not run the second rsync in the background and avoid using `wait` entirely. Though I'm guessing what the OP meant to do was run both `rsync` processes in parallel, which would mean backgrounding them _both_ (with `&`) and then using `wait`. In any case, I agree that this is the most straightforward way to fix the issue and is the one I'd choose based on the information in the question.