# How can I run a particular script every second?

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, watch

I have tried using crontab, but it is limited to minutes. Is there any other option?

I have also tried something like:

```
watch -n 1 sh /path-to-script/try.sh
```

But whenever I close the terminal it stops.
I want something which continuously works in the background.

Comment: I would focus on using `&` at the end of the command and also would read some about `disown` and `nohup` - see here for details https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and

Comment: Starting every second or starting a second after the previous one stopped? The latter is trivial, the first is a bit tougher. In the first case, you'd also want to consider what to do if one invocation takes longer than a second for some reason.

Comment: actually its a script to check if MySQL daemon is running or not... so script takes less than a second to execute.

Comment: I read about `disown` and `nohup`. So if I destroy the terminal on which the script is running it will destroy the program as well. @GeorgeVasiliou

Comment: @PrashantLuhar not with `nohup`, no. Using `nohup [command] &` makes the command ignore the terminal's attempts to kill child processes upon the terminal's logout.

Comment: scripts take less than a second, until they don't, and then things can get really ugly

Comment: I recommend using that command in conjunction with screen, see: https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a script with the `while` loop and `nohup`.

*the_script.sh*:

```
while :; do
  /path-to-script/try.sh
  sleep 1
done
```

Run `the_script.sh` immune to hangups:

```
nohup /path/to/the_script.sh > /dev/null
```

Replace `/dev/null` with some file path if you care what's in the `stdout`.

Comment: I did the same thing. It is running perfect... Thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have given, the best answer is likely the simplest one. Use a shell script with a infinite loop and a 1 second delay.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Program that checks if MySQL is running
while [ 1 = 1 ]; do
<your code here>
sleep 1
done
```

Have the script run outside a terminal. That way it runs in the background.

For a more specific answer, I'd need to know what command you use and what you do if it's not running. Eg. send a notification or email.

Comment: Actually I have tried this too, but whenever I close the terminal it  terminates the script..so the real problem here is how to run the script in background. And yes if its not running I send an email using `mailx` command

Comment: Put the script code in ~/.local/bin/notifymysqldown or /usr/bin/notifymysqldown and add it to one of the login startup scripts like this "notifymysqldown&". Whenever you log in the command will execute, in the background without a terminal window. To kill it off you'd need to open a task manager and look for notifymysqldown.sh and end it. You'd also want to add a if then else section so the script pauses a few minuted if it does go down so it doesn't send  a email every second.

Comment: Run this bash script in background, like `./script.sh &`, and then run command `disown`, then you can safely close your terminal. Another way is using `screen`.

Answer (score 0):

This routine will continuously run try.sh every second unless it is already running.  If already running, it will pause until the former execution ends.

```
loop_script.sh: 




while true; do  
   if [[ ! $(pgrep -x /path-to-script/try.sh) -gt 1 ]]; then  
      /path-to-script/try.sh  
   fi  
  
   sleep 1  
done
```

Execute this way:

```
nohup /path/to/loop_script.sh & > /dev/null
```

Then hit `^C` to regain console.

Must use `kill` command to stop `loop_script.sh`