# Howto Install google chrome in nixos?

Tags: nixos, nixpkgs

How can I install google chrome in nixos?
I have tried

```
nix-env -i google-chrome
nix-env -i google-chrome-stable
...
```

Which does not seem to work.
I also tried using the unstable branch

```
nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable
nix-channel --update
```

and then

```
nix-env -i unstable.google-chrome-stable
nix-env -i unstable.google-chrome
...
```

However it looks like the package should exist somewhere.
https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/master/pkgs/applications/networking/browsers/google-chrome

Does anybody know what I am missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by "Which does not seem to work?"

Comment: The packages are not found

Comment: Have you tried `nix-env -i nixos.google-chrome`?

Comment: just tried it. it also does not work

Answer (score 4):

[This NixOS FAQ question](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/FAQ/How_can_I_install_a_proprietary_or_unfree_package%3F) helped me:

> ### How
> can I install a proprietary or unfree package?
>
> You won't be
> able to install or search for an unfree package as a user, unless you
> explicitly enable it in *~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix* (the file
> and folder may need to be created):
>
> ```
> {   # [...]   allowUnfree =
> true; }
> ```
>
> When using NixOS, it is possible to
> enable unfree packages system-wide, then set in your
> `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:
>
> ```
> {   # [...]   nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true; }
> ```
>
> **Note
> that this alone will not allow you to search for or install packages
> with nix-env.**
>
> For temporary allowing unfree packages you
> can set the environment variable *NIXPKGS_ALLOW_UNFREE*, e.g.
>
> ```
> NIXPKGS_ALLOW_UNFREE=1 nix-env
> ```
>
> Note that we are not able
> to test or build unfree software on Hydra due to policy. Most unfree
> licenses prohibit us from either executing or distributing the
> software.

From the console with `nix-env`:

```
$ NIXPKGS_ALLOW_UNFREE=1 nix-env -qa | grep google-chrome
google-chrome-63.0.3239.132
google-chrome-beta-64.0.3282.71
google-chrome-dev-65.0.3311.3
```

["*Chapter 6. Global configuration*" of the NixPkgs manual](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#chap-packageconfig) goes even deeper into the details (especially section [6.3. Installing unfree packages](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-allow-unfree)).

I found the [rehno-lindeque/NixSetup.md](https://gist.github.com/rehno-lindeque/4eb5a325202c840cb8c9) gist exremely helpful with tons of extra resources and comments.

---

**edit**: Ditched `nix-env` a while back, and I use `nix-shell` instead; I only put installables in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` that need extra config, such as `vim`. This way I'm not dependent on channels as much (hope to learn flakes at one point..:).

So when I need a tool (e.g., `peek`, `google-chrome`, `treesheets`, etc.), this is what I go for:

```
$ NIXPKGS_COMMIT="dc849ffbcd93c2a23e99dcc94efb0962594b8b5f"
$ NIXPKGS_TARBALL="https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tarball/${NIXPKGS_COMMIT}"
$ PKGS="(callPackage (fetchTarball ${NIXPKGS_TARBALL}) {})"

$ NIXPKGS_ALLOW_UNFREE=1 nix-shell -v -p "${PKGS}.google-chrome"

$ nohup google-chrome-stable & > ~/.nohup.out # or /dev/null
$ disown
```

(See this great answer on [`nohup` vs `disown`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148698/85131).)

---

**edit-2**: A Nix shell can also be improvised on the terminal:

```
NIXPKGS_ALLOW_UNFREE=1                                  \
nix-shell -v -E                                         \
"let                                                    \
   pkgs = import (fetchTarball ${NIXPKGS_TARBALL}) {};  \
 in                                                     \
   pkgs.mkShell {                                       \
     buildInputs = with pkgs; [ google-chrome elixir ]; \
   }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to check channel name first:

```
$ nix-channel --list
nixpkgs https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable
```

Once you know the channel name, in this case `nixpkgs`, then you can proceed to installation:

```
$ nix-env -iA nixpkgs.google-chrome
installing ‘google-chrome-64.0.3282.186’
..................
```

Alternatively, you can search fully qualified name before perform the installation:

```
$ nix-env -qaP google-chrome                                                                                                                               
nixpkgs.google-chrome  google-chrome-64.0.3282.186
```