# Do `disown -h` and `nohup` work effectively the same?

Tags: bash, nohup, disown

`disown`

- causes a shell not to send SIGHUP to its disowned job when the shell terminates, and
- removes the disowned job from the shell's job control.

Is the first the result of the second?
In other words, if a process started from a shell is removed from the shell's job control by any way, will the shell not send SIGHUP to the process  when the shell terminates?

`disown -h`  still keeps a process under a shell's job control. Does it mean that `disown -h` makes a process still receives SIGHUP sent from the shell, but sets up the action of SIGHUP by the process to be "ignore"?  That sounds similar to `nohup`.

```
$ sleep 123 & disown -h
[1] 26103
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 123 &
$ fg 1
sleep 123
$ ^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 125
$ bg 1
[1]+ sleep 123 &
$ exit

$ ps aux | grep sleep
t        26103  0.0  0.0  14584   824 ?        S    15:19   0:00 sleep 123
```

Do `disown -h` and `nohup` work effectively the same, if we disregard their difference in using a terminal?

Thanks.

Comment: Another difference not discussed here is that if you aren't using `nohup`, you need to redirect stdin/stdout/stderr away from the TTY (should your original shell be connected to one) yourself. (OTOH, I actually consider that better practice than relying on an egregious hardcoded default like `./nohup.out`).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`nohup` and `disown -h` are not *exactly* the same thing.

With `disown`, a process is removed from the list of jobs in the current interactive shell.  Running `jobs` after starting a background process and running `disown` will not show that process as a job in the shell. A disowned job will not receive a `HUP` from the shell when it exits (but see note at end).

With `disown -h`, the job is not removed from the list of jobs, but the shell would not send a `HUP` signal to it if it exited (but see note at end).

The `nohup` utility ignores the `HUP` signal and starts the given utility.  The utility inherits the signal mask from `nohup` and will therefore also ignore the `HUP` signal. When the shell terminates, the process remains as a child process of `nohup` (and `nohup` is re-parented to `init`).

The difference is that the process started with `nohup` ignores `HUP` regardless of who sends the signal.  The disowned processes are just not *sent* a `HUP` signal *by the shell*, but may still be sent the signal from e.g. `kill -s HUP <pid>` and will not ignore this.

Note that `HUP` is only sent to the jobs of a shell if

- the shell is a login shell and the `huponexit` shell option is set, or
- the shell itself recieves a `HUP` signal.

Relevant bits from the `bash` manual (my emphasis):

> SIGNALS
>
> [...]
>
> The shell exits by default **upon receipt of a `SIGHUP`**.  Before exiting,
>       an interactive shell resends the `SIGHUP` to all jobs, running or
>       stopped.  Stopped jobs are sent `SIGCONT` to ensure that they receive the
>       `SIGHUP`.  To prevent the shell from sending the signal to a particular
>       job, it should be removed from the jobs table with the `disown` builtin
>       (see `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` below) or marked to not receive `SIGHUP`
>       using `disown -h`.
>
> **If the `huponexit` shell option has been set with `shopt`, `bash` sends a
>       `SIGHUP` to all jobs when an interactive login shell exits.**

> `disown [-ar] [-h] [jobspec ... | pid ... ]`
>
> Without options, remove each `jobspec` from the table of active
>                 jobs.  [...] If the `-h` option
>                 is given, each `jobspec` is **not removed** from the table, but is
>                 marked so that **`SIGHUP` is not sent to the job if the shell
>                 receives a `SIGHUP`**. [...]

Related:

- [Difference between nohup, disown and &](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886)

Comment: Thanks. `disown` makes a shell not sent SIGHUP to a child by removing the child from the shell's job list. How does `disown -h` achieve the same?

Comment: @Tim Not exactly. Both `disown` and `disown -h` makes `bash` mark the process as one to not send the `HUP` signal to. `disown` additionally removes it from the job table.  In my opinion, this builtin is confusing and does too many similar but not quite the same things.

Comment: Minor thing that probably is worth also mentioning is that `disown` is shell built-in in `ksh` and `bash` ( don't know about others ) but there's GNU `nohup`  standalone in `/usr/bin/nohup`  on Ubuntu-based distros and then there's [csh built-in](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0624/6j9vek5c1/index.html) (See NOTES section).

Answer (score 5):

**They are Different:**

- disown removes the job from the active jobs table. Then continues on with current job. With -h the proccess is *NOT* sent SIGHUP. It is instead left to die with the shell that contains it, when it recieves a SIGHUP.
- nohup ignores the HUP. Then anything that would have been passed to the terminal by the proccess closing instead goes to a file `nohup.out`.

  > nohup is defined by POSIX while disown is not.

Comment: What do you mean, "die with the shell that contains it"? Killing a parent process does not in and of itself kill a child. Programs whose terminals are closed *typically* die on account of failures related to attempts to interact with a file handle attached to the terminal's PTY, but if stdin/stdout/stderr are redirected elsewhere, that won't happen.