# Run multiple nohup commands in parallel without closing and opening a new terminal again

Tags: linux, terminal

Suppose I have directory_name1.....100
I need to run

```
nohup rsync -a --delete empty/directory_name1/ for 100s of directories
```

Now when I run this command for the first time , I have to close console and again open it to run it for directory_name2.

Basically I 100s of directorys and I want to run the above command on all 100 of directories in parallel without manually typing the above command by opening new terminal again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between nohup, disown and &](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and). Especially `&`, so it will be like `nohup … &`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I tried nohup...&  followed by enter key, and its not letting me put another command it just got executed.

Comment: Maybe your cursor is below the new prompt because of what `nohup` prints from the background, but this doesn't mean you cannot invoke commands. Press enter again.