# What is the real reason why nohup ./a.out dies when SSH session times out?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, process, signals

When you run `./a.out` in a terminal over SSH, and then the SSH session times out, `./a.out` is killed. Why is this? Some say that it's because of SIGHUP. But running `nohup ./a.out` still has the same problem in that when the SSH session times out, the `nohup ./a.out` process is still killed.

I've seen some say that it's because children are killed when the parent is killed. But I've seen it claimed elsewhere that this isn't normally the case.

An alternative explanation is that the stdout of ./a.out is tied to the terminal. Thus, after the terminal is killed, when ./a.out tries writing to the terminal, it will receive a SIGPIPE, which will cause it to be killed.

What is the real reason why `nohup ./a.out` dies when SSH times out?

Here is the actual command I'm running: `nohup ./a.out |& tee logs.out`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, `tee logs.out` writes to the terminal, and will be killed when it attempts to write after the SSH connection closes. This will in turn cause `nohup` to be killed as well, the next time `a.out` writes to its standard output.

If you want `nohup ./a.out` to survive, you should run it in the background with no pipe, and separately watch the `nohup.out` file:

```
nohup ./a.out &
tail -f nohup.out
```

or, using your log file,

```
nohup ./a.out > logs.out &
tail -f logs.out
```

Comment: By "running in the background" you mean launching it with the `&` operator, which I assume will bind the stdin and stdout pipes elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, with the `&` operator; but that doesn’t bind inputs or outputs anywhere, that’s `nohup`’s job.

Comment: @wonderer when you run `nohup ./a.out |& tee logs.out`, only `./a.out` is actually running with `nohup` to protect it from dying. The `tee` is a separate process but pipes fail if one part of them fails, so as soon as your session exits, `a.out` keeps running (nohup) but the `tee` fails (no nohup) so the entire pipe, including `a.out` is killed.

Comment: Is the nohup actually needed? I find that when I just run `./a.out &`, it continues running even after my SSH session exits.

Comment: See [Difference between nohup, disown and &](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/86440) for a discussion of this. `nohup` might not be necessary in your case, but it’s easier to use it than wonder ;-).