# What is the difference between echo 0>file.txt and echo 0 > file.txt?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I see that this has the behavior:

```
[root@divinity test]# echo 0 > file.txt
[root@divinity test]# cat file.txt
0
[root@divinity test]# echo 0> file.txt

[root@divinity test]# cat file.txt
```

I also noticed that if I include `""` then it works as expected:

```
[root@divinity test]# echo 0""> file.txt
[root@divinity test]# cat file.txt
0
```

I imagine this is all just part of IO redirection, but I do not quite understand what `echo 0>` is doing.

Comment: @zevzek "nohup experts" -- assuming bash or a shell with equivalent extensions, why would any expert use `nohup` instead of explicit redirection and `disown -h`? (Honest question: I suspect I may learn something from your response).

Comment: @Charles see [this Q&A on `nohup` v. `disown`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/86440).

Comment: @StephenKitt, ...hmm. That's comparing `nohup` against `disown` _without redirection_, whereas it's `disown` _with redirection_ (for all three of the standard FDs) that I'd call a fair comparison. Thus, almost all of the time spent in the analysis above is about the results of the subprocesses still inherting stdin/stdout/stderr.

Comment: @zevzek I sit corrected, thanks.

Comment: @zevzek What does using a subshell have to do with not needing to redirect stdin from `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In `echo 0 > file.txt`, with the spaces, `> file.txt` causes the shell to redirect standard output so that it is written to `file.txt` (after truncating the file if it already exists). The rest of the command, `echo 0`, is run with the redirections in place.

When a [redirection operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440) is prefixed with an unquoted number, with no separation, [the redirection applies to the corresponding file descriptor](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07) instead of the default. 0 is the file descriptor for *standard input*, so `0> file.txt` redirects standard input to `file.txt`. (1 is standard output, 2 is standard error.) The number is treated as part of the redirection operator, and no longer as part of the command’s arguments; all that’s left is `echo`.

You can see this happening more obviously if you include more content in the `echo` arguments:

```
$ echo number 0 > file.txt
$ echo number 0> file.txt
number
```

`number` shows up in the second case because standard output isn’t redirected.

This variant of the redirection operator is more commonly done with standard error, `2> file.txt`.

Redirecting standard input in this way will break anything which actually tries to read from its standard input; if you really want to redirect standard input, while allowing writes, you can do so with the `<>` operator:

```
cat 0<> file.txt
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer (upvoted), but I think it will benefit from 1 or 2 sentences better explaining what adding the space after the number is doing.

Answer (score -1):

File descriptor zero is the input stream. 0>filename will place the input stream into filename.  0 > filename will put 0 into the file filename.  Notice the spacing.

Comment: what does "will place the input stream into filename" mean, exactly?