# Kill backgrounded SSH when shell exits

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to spawn an SSH from my bash profile script that runs in the background for connection sharing (via its control socket). The problem I'm running into is a reliable way to ensure the SSH doesn't stay running once the TTY is closed (or more directly; once the parent bash shell has exited).

I know the shell can run commands (to terminate SSH) when it exits gracefully, but I'm trying to handle all possible scenarios where the shell doesn't get a chance to shut things down.

Is there a clever way I can do this?

The best idea I've had is

```
ssh -o PermitLocalCommand=yes -o LocalCommand='cat >/dev/null; kill $PPID' $HOST &
```

But this won't work because I need the command to only background once it has successfully started. Alternatively, I can't use `-fN` instead of the shell's `&` because the SSH `-f` only backgrounds after the `LocalCommand` has completed.

Also I'm trying to avoid running any command on the remote host. Otherwise I could probably do something like `ssh -fN $HOST 'cat >/dev/null'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate it when I answer my own question.

The solution I came up with is to use `ControlPersist=3600` when starting the master ssh process. This way if the shell doesnt exit gracefully and kill ssh, then it'll shut itself down after an hour of inactivity. Though I still use a trap on exit to shut ssh down cleanly.

```
ssh -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPersist=3600 -o ControlPath=/tmp/ssh-%u-%h-%p-%r -Nf $HOST
trap "ssh -o ControlPath=/tmp/ssh-%u-%h-%p-%r $HOST -O exit" exit
```

Comment: Cool recipe. Thanks for answering your own question.

Answer (score 3):

If your shell is a login shell you can stop SSH master connection from ~/.bash_logout file:

```
ssh -O exit hostname
```

If the shell isn't a login shell you can set a trap in your ~/.bashrc file just after spawning SSH:

```
ssh -fN hostname
trap 'ssh -O exit hostname' EXIT
```

Comment: This works if the shell exits gracefully, I'm trying to cover a scenario where the shell doesnt exit gracefully.

Answer (score -2):

[Keep SSH Sessions running after disconnection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection)

I don't know if this is what you are looking for but it helped me keep my program running after exiting the ssh shell.

Comment: No, not at all what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I dont think that it will work.