# after ssh login and during apt-get update, is it wrong to suddenly logout?

Tags: ssh, login

there's a raspberry pi that I ssh logged into
it works fine and then I `sudo apt-get update`ed it.

during the process, I just turned off the terminal thinking that the update process should be running on its own...

but after that, I tried to login again and it doesn't work.

Was it wrong for me to suddenly log out like that?

How can I make my raspberry do stuff even though I'm logged out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Was it wrong for me to suddenly log out like that?

Generally speaking, you don't want to suddenly stop the install process, as it leaves your file system in a somewhat undefined state. If you can get access to the console (either by ssh or directly) then try to [repair the installation](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1803582&p=11043917#post11043917) by typing:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

> How can I make my raspberry do stuff even though I'm logged out?

I would recommend [screen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen) for that. It creates a virtual shell that does not die on logouts, so you can reload it between logins.

Answer (score 1):

When the current session is destroyed, any applications running in it are also killed. [To prevent this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection), use `nohup` as so:

```
sudo nohup apt-get update &
```

or

```
sudo nohup apt-get install --yes package &
```

This will run in the background immediately return you to the prompt after you run it. The second version will automatically answer yes to any questions (which is important since you aren't at the interactive shell with this version). If something goes wrong, you'll either need to try it again normally or look at the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it's usually safe to rerun the update.

Assuming you are using a standard Linux....

The following logs are related to `apt` (and thereby to upgrade):

```
$ ls /var/log/apt/ | grep 'log$'
history.log
term.log
```

and also

```
/var/log/dpkg.log
```

Lastly, from this [post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=37399&p=320918) it seems that hard reboot (i.e. disconnecting the power) will allow you to log in the device again.

I hope you set it up to static IP, otherwise you can check your router.

Note: the update process, if haven't been run in a while, can take a few hours.