# How can I start a remote process on a remote machine via ssh?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, scripting

I want to start a shell script that resides on a remote machine. When I use

```
ssh user@example.com /path/to/script.sh
```

it needs the ssh connection to be open until the script has terminated.

But I need the script to continue to run, even after I close the ssh connection until the script finishes by itself. I just want to start a process and then forget about it.

How can I do this using ssh?

Thanks a lot!

P.S.: This is not a duplicate of [this stackechange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255159/does-temporary-disconnecting-of-ssh-session-affect-a-running-program).

Comment: This over on stackoverflow may help: [Getting ssh to execute a command in the background on target machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142/getting-ssh-to-execute-a-command-in-the-background-on-target-machine)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the problem is that when the SSH session is closed (by hitting ctrl-c, or closing the xterm), a HUP is sent to the process. To fork the process to background, add `&`, and to block the hup, use `nohup`:

`ssh user@example.com 'nohup sleep 300 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null </dev/null &'`

The ssh should start and the process will run on example.com in the background.

If you wish to monitor its progress, you can use `screen`, if you wish to do that then something similar to this will help:

`ssh user@example.com -t 'screen -D -RR -S this /bin/sleep 300'`

This creates a screen session named 'this' (-S), detaches an already running screen if attached elsewhere and reattaches here. Then starts /bin/sleep with a 5min wait.

Comment: If I wanted to save the output of the command to a file on the remote machine, where would the file path go (which dev/null should be replaced)?

Comment: `>/dev/null` redirects the output of STDOUT to `/dev/null`.  `2>/dev/null` redirects STDERR to `/dev/null`.  `</dev/null` reads the input of `/dev/null` for the program's STDIN (i.e., nothing).  If you want to capture the normal output of the program, change `>/dev/null`