# Keep a process alive after running it

Tags: ssh, process, exit, nohup

If I were to forget to run nohup as described [Keep SSH Sessions running after disconnection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection), would it be possible to keep a process alive **after** executing it. For example, I am running python program.py for the last 3 hours and forget to run the initial nohup command, could that process stay alive, or would I have to take the hit and start again?

Comment: so you mean in case you didn't start a tmux or screen session or the nohup command?

Comment: Yep. Would there be a way keep a running process alive :)

Comment: @mods while searching for duplicate (there's not really one here on unix SE, I accidentally clicked on something. Was mistake. I found this on superuser: http://superuser.com/a/96664/703934. Read the answer about the disown command. Even in your  link there's one answer which talks about the disown command. That should be what you're looking for.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't cover this case, but do scroll down a bit. Another high-scoring answer mentions `disown`.

Comment: I am voting to reopen the question: It is about applying `nohup` (or similar) **AFTER** a process was already initiated. This [superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/96664/471276) uses `disown -h`. This method IMHO could be explained in more detail here, too.