# SSH : launch task and leave it running even if I quit the terminal

Tags: ssh, command-line, terminal

I want to launch a task through ssh **and then exit my terminal** and have my task continuing on my ssh server.

I have tried a bunch of things **which did not work**, such as :

```
laptop$ ssh server@ipaddress
server$ mytask &
[1] 12345
server$ logout
```

Or

```
laptop$ ssh server@ipaddress
server$ mytask
(then hit [Ctrl]+[Z])
server$ logout
```

Or even

```
laptop$ ssh server@ipaddress -f "mytask"
(and then close my terminal)
```

But even in my last attempt, closing my terminal would stop the task.

How should I proceed?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think you need nohup tool `ssh userid@host "nohup command & "`  then you an close your local terminal but task will follow its own execution on remote host

Comment: ... or leave the connection open (with `ssh -n`), but `nohup` is better.

Comment: @francoisP Why don't you make an answer out of your suggestion? It can be one.

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection

Comment: Thank you very much @francoisP !! That's exactly what I needed :)